# Pra que serve um word boundary (\b) numa expressão regular?

Tags: regex

Há muito tempo, dei uma olhada a respeito do uso de *word boundary*, estudando sobre expressões regulares no PHP (PCRE Patterns).

Me deparei com o `\b` (que é chamado de *word boundary*).

Qual é a utilidade dele numa expressão regular?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

O `\b` (beta) é uma âncora assim como seus primos `^`(alfa) e `$`(omega). Uma vez adicionado em um dos lados da regex vai capturar padrão especificado no inicio, final ou **palavra** exata, isso significa que é válido apenas para letras, números e o underline (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`) que é o equivalente ao `\w`.

Entrada:

```
dialogo dia melodia diafragma dialeto radial bom-dia
```

[Âconra no início](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=94005) `\bdia` capturar strings(palavras) que contenham no início(não é o início da linha) o padrão `dia`, os itens que entram na captura são, **dia**logo, **dia**, **dia**fragma, **dia**leto e bom-**dia**

[Âncora no fim](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=94006) `dia\b` captura strings(palavras) onde o padrão especificado está no final, os itens capturados são: **dia**, melo**dia** e bom-**dia**

[Âncora exata](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=94007) `\bdia\b` captura a strings(palavras) extas **dia** e bom-**dia**

Referências

http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html

http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Answer (score 4):

Conforme já dito [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/420487/112052), o atalho `\b` é conhecido como [*word boundary*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (algo como "fronteira entre palavras").

Um detalhe importante é que ele é um *zero-length match* (*match* de tamanho zero), pois ele não corresponde a um caractere, e sim a uma posição da string. Sendo mais específico, ele corresponde a uma posição que possui um caractere alfanumérico antes e não possui um caractere alfanumérico depois (ou vice-versa).

> Na verdade a definição usa o termo "*word character*" em vez de "*alphanumeric character*", mas como achei que "caractere de palavra" (ou qualquer outra tentativa de tradução) não ficou bom, vou usar o termo "alfanumérico" mesmo. De qualquer forma, mais adiante tem uma discussão mais detalhada sobre esta definição.

Como já dito na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/110879/112052), o `\b` também acaba pegando o início e fim da string, desde que ela comece ou termine com um caractere alfanumérico. Por exemplo, se a string for `'abc.'`, então a regex `\b[a-z]` dá *match* na letra "a", pois o `[a-z]` indica uma letra de "a" a "z", e o `\b` indica uma posição que tem um caractere alfanumérico depois (no caso, a letra "a") e não possui um caractere alfanumérico antes, pois a letra está no início da string e portanto não tem nenhum caractere antes (interessante notar que não precisa ter um caractere não-alfanumérico antes, basta que **não tenha** um caractere antes - uma diferença sutil, porém importante na definição do `\b`).

Para ser mais preciso, o `\b` corresponde a qualquer posição da string que atenda a um desses critérios:

- início da string, se o primeiro caractere for alfanumérico
- final da string, se o último caractere for alfanumérico
- entre dois caracteres da string, se um deles é alfanumérico e outro não

Sua utilidade é para buscar palavras exatas em um texto, como já mencionado na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/110879/112052).

---

O problema é que, dependendo da *engine*/linguagem/ferramenta, a definição de "alfanumérico" pode variar.

No JavaScript, por exemplo, [o `\b` só considera caracteres ASCII](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/525347/112052), e portanto não funciona com letras acentuadas:

```js
console.log('café forte'.split(/\b/)) // [ 'caf', 'é ', 'forte' ]
```

Repare que o `split` separou "caf" e "é", pois ele considera que `é` não é um alfanumérico (ou sendo mais preciso, não é um *word character*). Vale notar que o `\b` faz a quebra nas posições em que os caracteres antes e depois não são do mesmo "tipo" (um é alfanumérico e o outro não), mas como ele é um *zero-length match*, nenhum caractere é excluído do resultado final, pois a quebra foi feita apenas na posição à qual o `\b` corresponde (é diferente, por exemplo, de `split(/,/)`, que faz a separação pela vírgula e também exclui todas as vírgulas do resultado).

Isso ocorre porque o `\b` geralmente considera que "alfanumérico" (ou "*word character*") são os caracteres que correspondem ao atalho `\w`. E no JavaScript o `\w` só considera os caracteres ASCII (é equivalente a `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`). Mesmo que exista a [*flag* `u`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499630/112052) (que habilita o "modo Unicode"), no JavaScript ele não muda o comportamento do `\w` e `\b`. Na [resposta já citada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/525347/112052) tem uma alternativa para considerar letras acentuadas.

Ou seja, as posições em que o `split` foi feito são:

- entre o primeiro "f" e o "é", pois é uma posição que possui um caractere alfanumérico antes ("f") e um não-alfanumérico depois ("é")
- entre o espaço (que está logo depois do "é") e a letra "f" (da palavra "forte"), pois é uma posição que possui um caractere não-alfanumérico antes (o espaço) e um alfanumérico depois ("f")

---

Em outras linguagens você pode mudar o comportamento do `\w` e `\b`. Em PHP, por exemplo, isso pode ser obtido usando-se a *flag* `u`, que faz com que o `\w` e `\b` passem a considerar caracteres acentuados. Ex:

```php
print_r(preg_split('/\b/', 'café forte')); // sem flag, considera somente ASCII
print_r(preg_split('/\b/u', 'café forte')); // com flag u, considera acentos e quaisquer outros caracteres Unicode
```

A saída do código acima é:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => caf
    [2] => é 
    [3] => forte
    [4] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => café
    [2] =>  
    [3] => forte
    [4] => 
)
```

Já no Python 3, tanto `\w` quanto `\b` consideram todos os caracteres Unicode (a menos que se use a *flag* `re.ASCII`):

```py
import re

s = 'café forte'
print(re.split(r'\b', s)) # ['', 'café', ' ', 'forte', '']
print(re.split(r'\b', s, flags=re.ASCII)) # ['', 'caf', 'é ', 'forte', '']
print(re.findall(r'\w+', s)) # ['café', 'forte']
print(re.findall(r'\w+', s, flags=re.ASCII)) # ['caf', 'forte']
```

---

Na maioria das *engines*, o `\b` é consistente com `\w`, ou seja, ele considera as posições entre dois caracteres da string na qual um deles corresponde a `\w` e o outro não. A exceção é Java, na qual `\b` por padrão está no "modo Unicode", enquanto `\w` por padrão só aceita ASCII. Ex:

```java
String s = "café forte";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(p.split(s)));

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\w+").matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

A saída é:

```
[café,  , forte]
caf
forte
```

Repare que `\b` considerou a letra acentuada corretamente, mas `\w` não. Para o `\w` considerar o acento, teria que mudar para `Pattern.compile("\\w+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS)`.

---

Resumindo:

- `\b` considera uma posição da string, não um caractere (e esta posição leva em conta as regras já mencionadas acima)
- seu comportamento pode ou não ser consistente com `\w` (geralmente é)
- pode ou não considerar caracteres Unicode por padrão, e pode ou não haver meios de configurar este comportamento