# Como remover uma palavra de uma string sem alterar palavras maiores que a contém

Tags: r, regex

Gostaria de remover uma palavra de uma string no R. Eu estava fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
> s <- "ele esta bem mas tambem esta triste"
> stringr::str_replace_all(s, "tambem", "")
[1] "ele esta bem mas  esta triste"
```

Até aqui, tudo bem. O problema é se eu quisesse tirar apenas a palavra "bem" do texto.

```
> stringr::str_replace_all(s, "bem", "")
[1] "ele esta mas tam esta triste"
```

Neste caso a palavra "tambem" fica cortada, e eu não queria que isso acontecesse.

Pensei em procurar a palavra entre espaços:

```
> stringr::str_replace_all(s, " bem ", " ")
[1] "ele esta mas tambem esta triste"
```

Mas aí, se eu procurasse a palavra "ele", ela não seria removida.
Existe alguma forma de remover todas as palavras, sem pensar em todos os casos?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eu não entendo de R, mas um pouco de regex, nesse caso especifico pode usar a âncora exata(`\b`) para casar exatamente a palava `bem`

```
stringr::str_replace_all(s, "\\bbem\\b", " ")
```

**Relacionado:**

[Pra que serve um boundary \b numa expressão regular?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110874/91)

Comment: Acho que a expressão `"\\b\\s?bem\\s?\\b"` seria melhor, pois desse jeito ficam três espaços seguidos na string final, e trocando `" "` por `""` ficam dois. Com essa expressão remove-se os espaços antes e depois da palavra (se houverem) e troca tudo por 1 único. Isso ainda não resolveria a palavra no fim da frase com pontuação (`bem.`), mas nesse caso talvez o ideal seria uma segunda expressão para remover resquícios.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando a expressão sugerida pelo @Molx `"\\b\\s?bem\\s?\\b"`, mas com a função `gsub()`

```
 gsub("\\b\\s?bem\\s?\\b","",s)
```