# REGEX - procurar expressões que NÃO contenham palavras específicas

Tags: regex, exceção

Estamos utilizando REGEX para normalizar dados farmacêuticos a partir de um campo string e precisamos distinguir strings muito semelhantes a partir de um comando de exceção.

Por exemplo, de uma maneira bem simples, temos os seguintes registros:

0,5 MG **COM** CT BL AL/AL X 30   ----> **COM** = Comprimido Simples

0,4 MG **COM REV** CT BL AL AL X 90   ----> **COM REV** = Comprimido Revestido

0,7 MG **COM LIB PROL** CT BL AL AL X 30   ----> **COM LIB PROL** = Comprimido Liberação Prolongada

Para identificar um Comprimido Revestido, utilizamos a sintaxe: **COM\sREV\s**

Para identificar o Comprimido Liber. Prolong., utilizamos a sintaxe: **COM\sLIB\sPROL\s**

Neste exemplo **simplificado** precisamos identificar um Comprimido Simples e para isso precisamos procurar uma expressão onde exista apenas **COM**, sem a existência das **palavras inteiras** REV e LIB. Algo parecido com a sintaxe:

**COM\s[^(REV|LIB)]**

.. mas essa sintaxe não funcionou. Alguém consegue ajudar?

**EDITADO**

Nem sempre o **REV** estárá imediatamente após o **COM**. A string poderá vir, por exemplo:

0,4 MG **COM CT REV** BL AL AL X 90   ----> ou com qualquer outras palavras.

A questão é não poder existir **REV** em nenhum ponto da string.

**EDITADO 27/07**

A sintaxe \bCOM\b\s(?!.*REV|.*LIB) funcionou bem para os casos que **REV** e **LIB** estão depois de **COM**, porém, não pode encontrar as expressões abaixo pois existe **REV** e **LIB** antes do **COM**

0,4 MG **REV** COM CT BL AL AL X 90

0,7 MG **LIB PROL** COM CT BL AL AL X 30

E então a sintaxe precisa ser abrangente para identificar o COM e descartar qualquer REV ou LIB

Algo como: (?!.*REV|.*LIB)\bCOM\b\s(?!.*REV|.*LIB)

É possível?

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo do resultado que queres obter? Queres organizar isso num objeto por exemplo? que linguagem estás a usar?

Comment: @Sergio, utilizaremos java para construção do código. No caso, precisamos varrer uma tabela inteira e classificar os registros de acordo com um campo de descrição, string, no qual tem todas as informações misturadas. Fiquei responsável por construir a sintaxe do REGEX para identificar os registros. Então, por exemplo, ao ler o campo string, quando encontrar **COM** sabemos que é um comprimido e quando encontrar **COM REV** sabemos que é um comprimido revestido, e assim por diante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Levando em consideração que as sentenças estarão separadas por `\n`, e que você não quer capturar as que não possuam as palavras `REV` e `LIB`, note que então `REVENDEDOR` e `LIBERADO` ira capturar.

A sentença poderia ser `^(?!.* (REV|LIB) .*).*$`.

Aplicando com os modificadores `gm`.

Veja funcionando em [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/fX6aJ4/1).

#### Explicação

- `^` ... `$` - deve a sentença vai do inicio ao fim da linha.
- `(?!)` - lookback de negação, se casar com esta sentença então de ignorar.
- `.* (REV|LIB) .*` qualquer frase que tenha `REV` ou `LIB`.
- `.*` qualquer coisa.
- Modificador `g` - global, todas que conseguir achar
- Modificador `m` - multiline, que disser que a cada `\n` ele considera como nova sentença.

#### Aplicando no PHP

```
$content = "
0,5 MG COM CT BL AL/AL X 30
0,4 MG COM REV CT BL AL AL X 90
0,7 MG COM LIB PROL CT BL AL AL X 30 
0,4 MG COM CT REV BL AL AL X 90
";

preg_match('~^(?!.* (REV|LIB) .*).*$~m', $content, $matchs);
```

#### Edição

Como comentado eu acaber esquecendo do `COM`.

A nova expressão ficaria assim `^(?!.* (REV|LIB) .*).* COM .*$`

#### Explicação

- `(?!.* (REV|LIB) .*)` - diz com o que "não deve casar".
- `.* COM .*` - diz com o que "deve casar".

Note os espaços no `COM` e no `(REV|LIB)` isso restringe para que seja só estas sentenças.

Como ele trata sendo duas expressões, a de "não deve casar com" e a "deve casar com", não importa se `REV|LIB` estão entes ou depois de `COM`, não sera capturado.

Veja funcionando no [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/fX6aJ4/3)

Comment: Obrigada Guilherme, no entanto eu preciso identificar o COM positivo. Já entendi a idéia. Muito obrigada pela ajuda.

Comment: Obrigada @GuilhermeLautert funcionou como eu precisava

Answer (score 2):

Se precisa fazer um busca exata por uma palavra a ancora(boundary) `\b` e com o Lookahead negativo(`?!`) para negar o grupo.

regex do exemplo da pergunta fica:

```
\bCOM\b\s(?!REV|LIB)
```

O retorno são quatro caracteres, `COM_` ou seja COM seguido de um espaço.

**Relacionado:**

[Significado de ?: ?= ?! ?<= ?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110874/91)

Pra que serve um boundary \b numa expressão regular?

Comment: Correto @rray, não tinha atualizado aqui para mim com sua resposta e acabei respondendo quase igual.

Comment: @DeniseDAmaro, `\bCOM\b\s(?!.*REV|.*LIB)` resolve?

Comment: Resolve sim, obrigada @rray. Como ficaria esta sentença se eu precisasse eliminar REV ou LIB antes do COM? Algo como (?!.*REV|.*LIB)\bCOM\b\s(?!.*REV|.*LIB)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
COM\s(?!REV|LIB)
```

[Exemplo da expressão em funcionamento.](http://refiddle.com/ik88)

Essa expressão só vai selecionar os COM que não forem precedidos por REV ou LIB.

**Explicação (Simples pois não tenho conhecimento avançado em Expressões regulares):**

- `?` = indica que há zero ou uma ocorrência do elemento precedente
- `!` = sinal de diferente
- `(?!)` = Negação de (?=), casa a ausência do padrão atual a partir da posição atual até o final, e também não inclui o padrão no casamento. Por exemplo, o padrão carro(?!amarelo) casará em "Um carro esportivo azul barato.", entretanto carro(?!azul) não casará.

Fonte: [Expressão regular](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular)

**Edit (Confirme novo cenário)**

Se o `REV` e `LIB` pode estar m qualquer ponto na string talvez a adição de coringas (`.*`) antes e depois da expressão negada já resolva. Algo assim:

```
COM\s(?!.*(REV|LIB).*)
```

[Exemplo funcional online.](http://refiddle.com/ik8b)

Comment: Sua resposta esta quase correta, nesse caso você não necessita do `[` e `]`, assim vc esta gerando um grupo de captura que inclui os caracteres que esta dentro dele, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/jS3zT6/1). Ajuste para `(?!REV|LIB)`

Comment: Pessoal, é quase isso. Funciona se o REV e o LIB estiver imediatamente após o COM. Mas no caso se tiver COM CT FR REV LIB, ele continuará encontrando.

Comment: Correto, você tem razão @GuilhermeLautert, vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: Obrigada Guilherme Lautert e Fernando. Funcionou nos exemplos que eu dei mas ainda falhou em um caso. Editei o post. Vcs podem olhar novamente pls?