# Como remover uma parte da string no começo ou apos o espaço?

Tags: php, regex

Preciso trocar nomes começados com HE por E como por exemplo

HELIANE HELIAS

para

ELIANE ELIAS

mas pode ser

GUILHERME HENRIQUE

e mudar para

GUILHERME ENRIQUE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se for apenas substituir o `HE` no inicio de nomes/palavras utilize o `\b`, dessa forma não são substituidos caracteres no 'meio' da string.

[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/5ox4uA)

```
<?php
   //exemplo 1
   $str = 'HELIANE HELIAS';
   $str = preg_replace('/\bHE/','E', $str);
   echo $str. PHP_EOL; //ELAINE ELIAS

   //exemplo 2
   $str = 'GHELIANE GHELIAS';
   $str = preg_replace('/\bHE/','E', $str);
   echo $str; //GHELIANE GHELIAS
```

**Relacionado:**

[Pra que serve um boundary (\b) numa expressão regular?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110874/91)

Comment: Deu certo, valeu demais, to aprendendo ainda expressao regular, ajudou muito

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer usando o `preg_replace`, criei uma função de exemplo:

```
function removeHe($nome) {
    $pattern = '/[^a-zA-Z ]{1}H(e)/i';
    $replace = '$1';
    return ucwords(preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $nome));
}
```

Ou se preferir, uma versão reduzida da função:

```
function removeHe($nome) {
    return ucwords(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z ]{1}H(e)/i', '$1', $nome));
}
```

> Uso:

```
echo removeHe('Guilherme Henrique');
echo '<br/>';
echo removeHe('HELIANE HELIAS') ;
echo '<br/>';
echo removeHe('Heliane Helias') ; // iniciando com he
echo '<br/>';
echo removeHe('Marcos Porche') ; // terminado com he
```

**Retorno:**

> Guilherme Henrique
>
> HELIANE HELIAS
>
> Heliane Helias
>
> Marcos Porche

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: esse nao deu certo, na verdade todos os nomes estao em maiusculos por exemplo GUILHERME HENRIQUE mesmo trocando o $pattern = '/H(e)/'; por $pattern = '/H(E)/'; ainda substitui ficando GUILERME ENRIQUE

Comment: só adicionar o "i" no final do pattern, já atualizei a resposta.

Comment: continua dando errado ate no retorno do site deu errado fica guilerme enrique

Comment: Em meu servidor funciona corretamente. Qual a sua configuração: Webserver, versão do PHP, etc.?

Comment: Qual o erro que está aparecendo?

Comment: ubuntu server lts padrao, continua trocando os nomes com lhe

Comment: Resolvido, favor me informar se deu certo.

Comment: Lembre-se de testar nomes terminados com HE, exemplo:  Marcos Porche