# Substituir todos os caracteres por "_" exceto o 1° caractere de cada palavra

Tags: javascript

Quero  substituir uma frase todos os carácteres  por `_` exceto  o 1° caractere de cada palavra Em JavaScript.

> Q____  S_________   U__ F____ T____ O_ C_______  P__

Ficaria  assim com a ideia usar em textos grandes. Quero criar uma função dentro deste código  em JavaScript:

```
function maiuscula(id){

    var letra=document.getElementById(id).value;
    letra=letra.split("");
    var tmp="";
        var Word="_";

    for(i=0;i<letra.length;i++){


    if(letra[i-1])
        {
          if(letra[i-1]==" ")
            {
                letra[i]=letra[i].replace(letra[i],letra[i].toUpperCase());
            }
        }

    else
    {
        letra[i]=letra[i].replace(letra[i],letra[i].toUpperCase());
    }

    tmp+=letra[i];

     }

    document.getElementById(id).value=tmp;
```

Para ser usada em um input:

```
<input type="text" id="billing:firstname" onkeyup="maiuscula('billing:firstname')" name="billing[firstname]" value="" title="Nome" class="t1 required-entry"/>
```

Comment: quer substituir todos os caracteres de uma palavra, a excepção do primeiro, por "_"? é isso?

Comment: E em que linguagem de programação você quer fazer isso? Já tentou algo? Já tem alguma experiência com programação? Sua pergunta está sendo negativada porque não está clara.

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque não tem dúvida específica de programação nela, conforme [a documentação.](/help/on-topic). Você pode [edit] a postagem a qualquer momento, se achar que é possível deixar em conformidade com a orientação.

Comment: @claudio Você quer substituir todos os caracteres exceto a primeira letra de cada palavra (maiúscula ou minúscula)?

Comment: Obg ! ja tentei sim em javascript  mas como sou iniciante nao tive sucesso.

Comment: Olá stderr  - entao preceiso que substitua o o texto  deixando apanas a 1° letra  maiúscula  preferencialmente

Answer (score 4):

Uma outra alternativa é usar o [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) em conjunto com a [expressão regular](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `/\B\w/g`:

```
var valor = 'stack overflow em portugues';

var substituto = valor.replace(/\B\w/g, '_');
// s____ o_______ e_ p________
```

Onde [`\B`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-word-boundary) é o oposto de [`\b`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary), `\b` limita-se em corresponder a um padrão ou palavra exata, dependendo da posição em que for inserido, por exemplo, a expressão `\b\w` corresponde a `f` e `b` em `foo bar`, o contrário `\w\b` corresponde a `o` e `r`.

A expressão `\B\w` corresponde a `oo` e `ar` e `\w\B` a `fo` e `ba`. Nesta outra pergunta tem mais detalhes sobre: [Pra que serve um *boundary* (`\b`) numa expressão regular?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110874/6454)

O modificador [`g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global) indica que deve ser feita uma busca global, não retornar no primeira vez que o padrão for correspondido.

Para exibir as letras restantes em maiúsculo, use o [`string.toUpperCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase):

```js
var valor = 'stack overflow em portugues';
var substituto = valor.replace(/\B\w/g, '_').toUpperCase();

console.log(substituto);
// S____ O_______ E_ P________
```

Comment: Obrigado pessoal ! funcionou direitinho.

Comment: @claudio Se possível marque a resposta como "aceita" clicando na seta abaixo da pontuação!

Answer (score 1):

A lógica a seguir vai resolver seu problema:

```js
var text = "QUOTE";

 function replaceString(text){
    var textRefact;
    for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
       if(i == 0){
       textRefact = text.charAt(i);
    }else{
       textRefact += "_";
    }
 }
   return textRefact;
 }

var newText = replaceString(text);

console.log(newText);
```