# Pegar letras da string do nome

Tags: php

Preciso pegar a primeira letra do nome e a primeira apos o espaço, no caso seria assim:

```
$string = 'Renan Rodrigues';
```

Resultado esperado: 'RR';

Como fazer isto ?

Comment: A string pode ter um terceir ou quarto nome?

Comment: @rray podera ter sim

Comment: optaria por usar regex, por ser mais performático e garantir uma maior segurança qto a acentos e outras situações que vc não espera.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode pegar o primeiro caracter da string, apenas indexando a variável como zero. Para pegar a primeira letra após o espaço pode usar `str_pos()` que determinará a posição do espaço, com ela use `substr()` para copiar o trecho desejado (a partir da posição do espaço um caracteres, no caso o R)

```
echo $string[0] . substr($string, strpos(' ', $string), 1);
```

Outra alternativa é chamar a função `strstr()` ela vai 'cortar' a string em dois pedaços, na primeira chamada (com o terceiro argumento) será retornada a parte a esquerda do delimitador, já a segunda retornar a parte a direita.

```
$string = 'Renan Rodrigues';
$iniciais = strstr($string, ' ', true)[0] . trim(strstr($string, ' ')[1]);
```

Caso a sua string mais de dois itens para pegar a primeira letra ou se por acaso a string tenha dois ou mais espaços seguidos recomendo o uso de uma função mais elaborada como:

```
function iniciais($str){
    $pos = 0;
    $saida = '';
    while(($pos = strpos($str, ' ', $pos)) !== false ){
        if(isset($str[$pos +1]) && $str[$pos +1] != ' '){
            $saida .= substr($str, $pos +1, 1);
        }   
        $pos++;
    }
    return $str[0]. $saida;
}


$arr = ['Abc Jr Silva', 'AB      ', 'TEste     123, Zxw', 'A1 B2 C3 D4', 'Nome'];
foreach($arr as $item){
    var_dump(iniciais($item));
}
```

Saída:

```
string 'AJS' (length=3)
string 'A' (length=1)
string 'T1Z' (length=3)
string 'ABCD' (length=4)
string 'N' (length=1)
```

**Abordagem com regex**

A regex `\b\w` captura cada inicia de uma palavra.

```
$string = 'João Silva Sauro Jr';
preg_match_all('/\b\w/u', $string, $m);
echo implode('',$m[0]);
```

Saída:

```
JSSJ
```

**Relacionado:**

[Pra que serve um boundary (\b) numa expressão regular?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110874/91)

Answer (score 5):

Dá pra fazer assim:

```
$partes = explode(' ', $nome);

echo $partes[0][0]
echo $partes[1][0]
```

Exemplo no [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/3rQNL0)

Mas como a primeira letra pode conter um caractere acentuado, poderia dar algum erro de codificação. Então, você poderia fazer:

```
 echo mb_substr($partes[0], 0, 1, 'UTF-8');
 echo mb_substr($partes[1], 0, 1, 'UTF-8');
```

Exemplo no [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/ib5Qia)

Answer (score 4):

Tente assim:

```
$string = 'Renan Rodrigues';
$nomeSeparado=explode(" ",$string);
$iniciais= substr($nomeSeparado[0],0,1).substr($nomeSeparado[1],0,1);
echo $iniciais;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 public function index(){          

     // Array ( [0] => Raylan [1] => Soares [2] => Campos )     
     $names = explode(' ', Auth::user()->name);

     // Variavel recebe a verificação se tem mais de dois nomes,
     // caso tenha irá armazenar primeiro e ultimo nome.       
     $twoNames = (isset($names)) ? $names[0] . ' ' . end($names) : $names[0];

     // Variavel recebe a primeira letra do primeiro nome e a 
     //primeira letra do último nome função end() pega a ultimo valor do array.     
     $iniciais = strstr($twoNames, ' ', true)[0] . trim(strstr($twoNames, ' ')[1]);

     // retorna para a view o nome e ultimo nome na variavel $twoNames, e as 
     //Iniciais desse nome na variavel $iniciais.
     return view('index',compact('twoNames','iniciais'));
}
```

Comment: Por que o nome `index()`? Não seria mais descritivo `iniciais()` ou `monograma()`?

Answer (score -3):

Minha primeira resposta estava inadequada.

Acho que a function a seguir pode útil, ela considera alguns casos
como a remoção de partículas de ligação como "da","do", "dos".

Mas não vai funcionar para nomes com alguns caracteres, como por exemplo caracteres do alfabeto cirílico

```
<?php
function getNameInitials(string $name, int $max = 5){
    $name = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $name);
    /// remove acentuações

    $string = preg_replace("/[^\p{L}\s]/u", "", $name);
    // remove qualquer caracter que não seja letra ou espaço

    $remove = ['do', 'dos', 'da', 'de', 'e', 'd'];
    // partículas de ligação a serem ignoradas

    $string = preg_replace("/\b(" . implode("|", $remove) . ")\b/i", "", $string);
    // remove as partículas de ligação informadas em $remove

    preg_match_all("/\b(\w)/u", $string, $matches);
    // obtém as iniciais

    $initials = strtoupper(implode("", $matches[0]));
    return substr($initials, 0, $max);
    // retorna as inicias respeitado o limite informado
}

$name = "Ruan    Rodrigues d' Júnior e Silva";
$initials = getNameInitials($name, 3);
echo $initials;
?>
```