# Como criar uma função que valida se há uma função MySQL em uma determinada string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Estou procurando uma função que identifique (retornar verdadeiro) se houver uma função MySQL em uma string.
Estes seriam alguns exemplos de possibilidade de entrada para função.

```
<?php

$randomstrings = [
    "foo", //String comum
    "NOW()", //Função sem parâmetros
    "CONCAT_WS('foo','doo','boo')", //fun. com parâmetros
    "ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-48.23456,20.12345]}'))", //Funções dentro de funções
    "ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(@json))", //Variávies dentro da função
    "patrimony", //Não identificar paTRIMony como a function TRIM()
]

 foreach ($randomstrings as $value) {
 $functionList = array('LOAD_FILE', 'sql_to_decimal', '@userid', 'COALESCE', 'getVersaoEO', 'getPessoaById', 'CONVERT', 'IS NULL', 'IS NOT NULL',
            'ST_GeomFromText', 'ST_AsGeoJSON', 'ST_GeomFromGeoJSON', 'ST_AsText', 'CONCAT_WS', 'CONCAT', /*'TRIM',*/ 'json_extract', 'JSON_OBJECT', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP');
        foreach ($functionList as $function) {

            $find = strpos(strtolower($value), strtolower($function));
            if (!($find === false)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
 }
```

Acredito que isso possa ser feito com expressões regulares ou alguma outra função de comparação.

Comment: Apenas como nota, essa função não deve ser utilizada para barrar algum tipo de SQL-Injection. O propósito dela é apenas identificar dentro de uma string se há a ocorrência de um caracter especifico em formato de função ou variável MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quiser apenas saber se uma ou mais funções existem na string, pode montar um regex procurando pelo termo exato com a âconra `\b`. Ao colocar um termo entre `\b` significa que está procurando por uma palavra completa e não um trecho, por isso não captura `patrimony` mesmo tendo o termo `TRIM` no meio/dentro.

```
$randomstrings = [
        "foo", //Non-function strings
        "NOW()", //Without parameters
        "CONCAT_WS('foo','doo','boo')", //With parameters
        "ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-48.23456,20.12345]}'))", //Maybe functions inside functions
        "ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(@json))", //Variables as parameters
        "patrimony", //Do not identify paTRIMony as  a function TRIM()
];

$functionList = array('LOAD_FILE', 'sql_to_decimal', '@userid', 'COALESCE', 'getVersaoEO', 'getPessoaById', 'CONVERT', 'IS NULL', 'IS NOT NULL','ST_GeomFromText', 'ST_AsGeoJSON', 'ST_GeomFromGeoJSON', 'ST_AsText', 'CONCAT_WS', 'CONCAT', /*'TRIM',*/ 'json_extract', 'JSON_OBJECT', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP');

foreach ($randomstrings as $value) {
    foreach($functionList as $function){
        if(preg_match("#\b$function\b#i", $value)){
            echo 'procurou por: '. $function  .' acho em: '. $value .'<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Retorna:

```
procurou por: CONCAT_WS acho em: CONCAT_WS('foo','doo','boo')
procurou por: ST_GeomFromGeoJSON acho em: ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-48.23456,20.12345]}'))
procurou por: ST_AsText acho em: ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-48.23456,20.12345]}'))
procurou por: ST_GeomFromGeoJSON acho em: ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(@json))
procurou por: ST_AsText acho em: ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(@json))
```

**Relacionado:**

[Pra que serve um boundary (\b) numa expressão regular?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110874/91)

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho quando o `now` está na lista de funções e na lista de strings está como `NOW()` ou `NOW ()` ele falha? Nas lista de funções só deve ir o nome. Não entendi muito bem.

Comment: Por exemplo, se eu escrever "NOW()" e talvez por "NOW ()" com um espaço entre o início do parênteses eu teria que ter ambas formas na minha lista de funções, haveria uma fora de opicionalmente ele procurar pelas duas formas usando o mesmo item da lista?

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho uma opção é guardar todos os nomes de funçõe sem os parenteses e na hora de fazer a regex adicionar essa regra. A regex fica: `#\b$function\b\s*\(#i` ela fiz procure o nome da função seguido ou não de espaços tab em qualquer quantidade seguido de um abre parentese.

Comment: Entendi, nesse caso farei 2 arrays, um para palavras e um para funções e aplicarei a segunda regex para que valide também o "(".