# Como buscar por uma palavra em um arquivo e puxar a frase onde ela se encontra junto com o resultado?

Tags: python

Estou precisando buscar por palavras em um arquivo de livros (`vidas secas.txt`).
Mas quero que ela traga também a frase onde ela se encontra. Tem como fazer isso?

Aqui está meu programa:

```
arquivo =open('Vidas Secas.txt','r')
quantidade = 0
palavras =[]
y = 0
for linha in arquivo :
    linha = linha.rstrip()
    linha = linha.lstrip()
    #print('Linha original ', linha)
    p = linha.split(' ')
    #print('linha processada ', p)
    palavras = palavras + p

#print(palavras)

arquivo.close()
x = input ('Digite a palavra desejada: ')
for palavra in palavras:
    if x == palavra:
        quantidade = quantidade + 1
    if palavra[0:len(x)] == x:
        quantidade = quantidade + 1
print(quantidade)

arquivo.close()
```

Comment: Para não ter de ler todo o arquivo sempre, você teria de guardar todas as frases - do inicio ao ponto final de cada uma - e todas as palavras contidas nessa frase. Muitas palavras se repetiriam entre frases. Portanto quando o usuário digitasse a palavra você procuraria em todas as palavras de todas as frases e mostraria todas as frases onde essa palavra se encontra.

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor, por favor? Não entendi muito bem, e sou iniciante em python, e tenho que apresentar um projeto amanhã. Minha parte é justamente fazer um programa que ao buscar por uma palavra o programa puxe a fraze onde está o programa. Eu fiz assim como teste: x='Esta é uma linda casa'. palavras=x.split(' ') Como teste palavras[3]m (linda) i=3: j=i+1 (O j avança pelos caracteres até encontrar um .) k=i-1 (o k retrocede até encontrar uma letra maiúscula) Depois fiz len e depois n=len(palavras [j]) E palavras [j] [n+1] Parei aí, não conssigo avançar mais. Da mensagem de erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução ideal depende muito da sua definição de "frase" e "palavra".

A abordagem mais simples (e ingênua, e provavelmente errada) é considerar que cada linha é uma frase e todas as palavras são separadas por espaços:

```
# palavra a ser buscada
busca = input('Digite a palavra desejada: ')

with open('Vidas secas.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo: # assume que cada linha do arquivo é uma frase
        # se a palavra está na linha, imprime a linha ("frase") inteira
        if busca in linha.strip().split():
            print(linha)
```

O método [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) remove os espaços e a quebra de linha no final da linha, e [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.split) separa a linha em várias partes, separadas por espaços. O resultado é uma lista das palavras, e em seguida basta verificar se a palavra a ser buscada está nesta lista.

Outro detalhe é o uso de `with`, que automaticamente fecha o arquivo, sem que você precise se preocupar com isso. Também coloquei o *encoding* como parâmetro, que você pode mudar de acordo com o encoding em que o arquivo está ([veja a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) para mais detalhes).

---

Mas essa abordagem, como eu já disse, é simplificada demais, e bastante propensa a erros. Veja por exemplo esse trecho do livro Vidas Secas:

> – Anda, excomungado.

Esta frase possui 2 palavras: "Anda" e "excomungado". Mas se eu usar `split()`:

```
print('– Anda, excomungado.'.split())
```

O resultado é a seguinte lista:

> ```
> ['–', 'Anda,', 'excomungado.']
> ```

O hífen foi considerado uma palavra, e as outras duas palavras são `"Anda,"` (com a vírgula no final) e `"excomungado."` (com o ponto no final). Ou seja, se você buscar por somente "Anda" (sem a vírgula), esta linha não será encontrada.

Então a solução é usar algum critério mais sofisticado, usando expressões regulares (regex), por exemplo. Para isso você pode usar o [módulo `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Uma primeira tentativa seria usar `\b` (que marca a "fronteira de palavra", ou seja, o início e fim de uma palavra, ver mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/420487/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110874/112052)) e `\w+` (um ou mais caracteres alfanuméricos) para representar a "palavra". (`\w` não é a melhor opção, mas por enquanto vamos usá-la para manter as expressões mais curtas - depois eu explico os problemas desta opção e dou outra alternativa).

Eu também coloco `\w+` entre parênteses [para que se forme um grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), pois aí a palavra que a regex encontrar estará disponível pelo método `group`, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
import re

regex_palavras = re.compile(r'\b(\w+)\b')
# palavra a ser buscada
busca = input('Digite a palavra desejada: ')

with open('Vidas secas.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo:  # assume que cada linha do arquivo é uma frase
        # buscar as palavras da linha, usando a regex
        for match in regex_palavras.finditer(linha.strip()):
            if busca == match.group(1): # group(1) contém a palavra
                print(linha)
                break
```

Agora você pode buscar por "Anda" (sem vírgula), que a frase "- Anda, excomungado" será encontrada, pois a vírgula será desconsiderada.

Também coloco um `break` para interromper o `for match ...`, pois se a palavra ocorrer duas vezes na mesma frase, eu não preciso imprimí-la duas vezes. Se eu já encontrei a palavra, eu imprimo a frase e não preciso mais verificar o restante dela.

---

O problema esta abordagem é que `\w` também aceita dígitos ***** e o caractere `_`. Ou seja, `123` e `a_b` serão consideradas palavras. Claro que, se você tem "certeza absoluta" que esses casos não ocorrem (ou se for somente para um exercício, ou qualquer outro motivo que faça com que estes casos não "precisem" ser validados), poderíamos até parar por aqui (veja a alternativa para `\w` mais abaixo).

***** *No Python 3, [os dígitos aceitos](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-27) por `\w` são qualquer caractere da [categoria Unicode "Number, Decimal Digit"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm), o que inclui caracteres como `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩`, entre outros (veja [esta resposta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414230) para mais detalhes). No [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), por padrão ele só reconhece os dígitos de 0 a 9, e para reconhecer os demais dígitos, é preciso habilitar a [opção `UNICODE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) ([exemplo](https://ideone.com/suh8te)).*

Mas há outros detalhes que talvez você precise levar em conta. Por exemplo, *"Arrastaram-se"* tem uma ou duas palavras? O código acima considera que são duas ("Arrastaram" e "se").

E quanto a "guarda-roupa", considera-se uma ou duas palavras? Talvez o hífen também devesse ser considerado parte uma palavra, desde que tenha pelo menos uma letra antes e depois, certo? Mas não se esqueça do apóstrofo, como em "gota-d'água", que também tem que ser incluído na lista de "caracteres que formam uma palavra". Se usarmos o código acima, elas serão consideradas mais de uma palavra ("guarda" e "roupa"; "gota", "d" e "água").

*(Provavelmente o livro não tem as palavras supracitadas, mas podem haver outras palavras compostas e/ou com apóstrofos, e você deve decidir se vai considerá-las uma única palavra ou não).*

Uma primeira tentativa de cobrir estes casos, considerando que palavras compostas contam como apenas uma palavra:

```
regex_palavras = re.compile(r"\b((?:\w+(?:'\w+)?)(?:-(?:\w+(?:'\w+)?))*)\b")
```

Basicamente, `(?:` define um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap): faz com que os parênteses não estejam disponíveis no método `group`. Isso faz com que não sejam criados grupos que eu não estou interessado (só preciso do primeiro, que contém a palavra inteira).

Depois eu uso `'\w+` para definir "um apóstrofo seguido de um ou mais caracteres alfanuméricos", e coloco tudo dentro de parênteses, seguido de `?`, o que torna este trecho opcional. Faço a mesma coisa para o hífen, que pode estar seguido outros caracteres alfanuméricos (que também pode ter um apóstrofo no meio). Só que o trecho do hífen possui um `*` depois, que significa "zero ou mais ocorrências", ou seja, pode ou não ter este trecho todo depois do hífen, e pode ter mais de um hífen (como em "água-de-colônia").

Com isso, consideramos palavras simples e compostas, com ou sem apóstrofo, como se fossem uma coisa só.

Apesar disso, esta regex ainda possui o problema de aceitar dígitos e `_`, [veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/DeoEb0/2/) em exemplo dela funcionando. Se quiser ser mais específico nos caracteres que a regex pode ter, basta trocar `\w` por algo como `[a-záéíóúâêîôûãõç]`, que só vai aceitar as letras de "a" a "z", os caracteres acentuados e a cedilha. Coloque mais caracteres dentro dos colchetes, caso precise (para textos em espanhol, por exemplo, precisaria colocar o `ñ`).

Outro detalhe é que `\w` considera letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, mas a alternativa `[a-záéíóúâêîôûãõç]` só considera as minúsculas. Então não esqueça de setar a opção `IGNORECASE` para que letras maiúsculas também sejam consideradas:

```
regex_palavras = re.compile(.... , flags = re.IGNORECASE)
```

Se quiser, também pode trocar o `+` que está depois do `\w` por alguma quantidade específica. `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências", o que quer dizer que os artigos "a" e "o" também são considerados palavras. Se quiser somente palavras com duas letras ou mais, por exemplo, troque o `+` por `{2,}`. Você também pode colocar o tamanho máximo, se quiser: `{2,20}`, por exemplo, vai aceitar entre 2 e 20 caracteres.

Lembrando que estes limites se aplicam a cada trecho específico. Por exemplo:

```
\w{2,20}(?:'\w{2,20})?
```

Significa "entre 2 e 20 caracteres alfanuméricos", seguido de apóstrofo, seguido de mais caracteres alfanuméricos (entre 2 e 20). Ou seja, esta palavra pode ter até 40 caracteres (20 antes do apóstrofo e 20 depois).

Enfim, escolha a sua definição de "palavra" e mude a regex de acordo com o que precisar.

---

Outro ponto a considerar é que pode ter mais de uma frase na mesma linha. Podemos considerar que "frases" são delimitadas por sinais de pontuação (ponto final, exclamação e interrogação), por exemplo. Então bastaria, para cada linha, fazer esta separação, antes de verificar as palavras:

```
regex_frases = re.compile(r"[.!?]+")

with open('Vidas secas.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo:
        # uma linha pode ter várias frases
        for frase in regex_frases.split(linha.strip()):
            for match in regex_palavras.finditer(frase):
                if busca == match.group(1):
                    print(frase)
                    break
```

Eu usei como critério de separação das frases a regex `[.!?]+`: uma ou mais ocorrências de qualquer um dos sinais de pontuação (ponto final, exclamação ou interrogação). Assim já estão inclusas frases que terminam com `...` e `?!`, por exemplo.

Mas claro que isso não resolve tudo. Neste trecho:

> A seca aparecia-lhe como um fato necessário – e a obstinação da criança irritava-o.

São 2 frases (*"A seca aparecia-lhe como um fato necessário"* e *"e a obstinação da criança irritava-o."*) ou é uma só? A solução acima considera que é apenas uma única frase.

Se quiser considerar que são duas, não podemos simplesmente incluir o hífen como separador, pois aí "aparecia-lhe" também será quebrado em duas "frases". Podemos considerar então que o critério é "sinais de pontuação **ou** hífen com espaço antes e depois", por exemplo:

```
regex_frases = re.compile(r"(?: \– )|[.!?]+")

with open('Vidas secas.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo:
        # uma linha pode ter várias frases
        for frase in regex_frases.split(linha.strip()):
            for match in regex_palavras.finditer(frase):
                if busca == match.group(1):
                    print(frase)
                    break
```

Neste caso, o trecho anterior é separado em duas frases. Se eu buscar por "fato", por exemplo, o resultado será a frase *"A seca aparecia-lhe como um fato necessário"* (o conteúdo depois do hífen é considerado outra frase).

Enfim, quanto mais casos diferentes aparecerem, mais complexa vai ficando a regex. Decida o que vai ser considerado "frase" e mude o código conforme suas decisões.

---

A solução anterior assume que não há frases que se estendem por mais de uma linha. Mas pode ser que isso aconteça (uma frase começa em uma linha e termina em outra, vai saber quem criou esse arquivo), então o jeito é ler todo o conteúdo do arquivo em uma única variável e em seguida usar as expressões regulares neste conteúdo:

```
with open('Vidas secas.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as arquivo:
    # todo o conteúdo do arquivo em uma única variável
    conteudo = arquivo.read()

# separar o conteúdo em frases
for frase in regex_frases.split(conteudo):
    for match in regex_palavras.finditer(frase):
        if busca == match.group(1):
            print(frase)
            break
```

---

Há ainda outras melhorias, como por exemplo guardar a lista de frases em uma variável, para que não precise ler o arquivo toda hora (assumindo que várias buscas podem ser feitas de uma vez):

```
# guardar a lista de frases, assim não preciso ler o arquivo de novo
frases = regex_frases.split(conteudo)

for frase in frases:
   for match in ... etc
```

E se quiser fazer uma busca *case insensitive* (sem diferença entre letras maiúsculas e minúsculas), você pode usar o método [`casefold()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.casefold), que retorna uma versão da string própria para este tipo de comparação. No caso, basta mudar o `if` dos exemplos anteriores para:

```
if busca.casefold() == match.group(1).casefold():
    # palavra encontrada (sem diferenciar maiúsculas de minúsculas)
```

O método `casefold()` foi introduzido no Python 3.3. Caso sua versão seja anterior, a alternativa é usar o método [`lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.lower).

Comment: Olá, muito obrigado. Eu não entendi completamente o que você quis duizer, mas vioyu perguntar para o meu professor. Estou aprendendo python desdde o começo do ano, pois faço técnico para informática integrado ao ensino médio e sou do primeiro ano. Obrigado! Mas, eu copiei o seu código, e quando executo o  arquivo no cmd com o python 3.7 da a mensagem: File "Atividade 1.py", line 6
    for frases = regex_frases.split(conteudo)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
O que eu faço?

Comment: @ArthurVidal Eu sugiro que [edite a sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/348044/edit) e adicione o código completo que gera esta mensagem, pois erro de sintaxe é geralmente pq faltou algum detalhe no programa (que é difícil de ver assim com código "solto" nos comentários)

Comment: @ArthurVidal Acho que entendi, vc colocou `for frases = regex_...` mas na verdade, ou vc faz `frases = regex_...` (e depois faz o for) ou então faz `for frases in regex_...`

Comment: Não entendi, mas onde é pra colocar esse comando exatamente? na linha 6, onde está o for frases = regex_frases.split (conteudo)?

Comment: O meu código está assim: with open('Vidas secas.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as arquivo:
    # todo o conteúdo do arquivo em uma única variável
    conteudo = arquivo.read()

# separar o conteúdo em frases
for frases = regex_frases.split(conteudo)

for frase in frases:
   for match in ...
        if busca == match.group(1):
            print(frase)
            break

Comment: @ArthurVidal  Seria assim: https://ideone.com/1lUEeR

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa dividir o texto em frases. O exemplo abaixo usa o ponto final (o caractere `.`) como delimitador de frases:

```
with open('Vidas Secas.txt') as arquivo:
    texto = arquivo.read()

frases = [frase.strip() for frase in texto.split('.')]
pesquisa = input('Digite a palavra desejada: ')

for frase in frases:
    if palavra in frase.split():
        print(frase)
```