# Diferença entre os metacaracteres \b e \B

Tags: r, regex

Os metacaracteres `\b` e `\B` são [âncoras](http://rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#anchors) que marcam os limites de uma string (onde ela começa, termina ou ambos). Funciona segundo o padrão ASCII, contendo apenas `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. Isto é, só serão identificados as partes da string que contenham este padrão.

Tenho esta variável:

```
x <- c('melodia', 'bom-dia!', 'bom_dia!', 'radial', 'dia', 'diafragma')
x
```

E os seguintes códigos com uso de `\b`:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

`\bdia` marca o início (tudo que começa com `dia`, segundo o padrão ASCII):

```
str_subset(string = x, regex(pattern = '\\bdia'))
[1] "bom-dia!"  "dia"       "diafragma"
```

`dia\b` marca o final (tudo que termina com `dia`, segundo o padrão ASCII):

```
str_subset(string = x, regex(pattern = 'dia\\b'))
[1] "melodia"  "bom-dia!" "bom_dia!" "dia"
```

`\bdia\b` marca o intervalo (tudo que começa e termina com dia, segundo o padrão ASCII):

```
str_subset(string = x, regex(pattern = '\\bdia\\b'))
[1] "bom-dia!" "dia"
```

`bom-dia` é retornado pois o `-` não está contido no padrão ASCII informado.

Agora com uso de `\B`:

```
str_subset(string = x, regex(pattern = '\\Bdia'))
[1] "melodia"  "bom_dia!" "radial"  

str_subset(string = x, regex(pattern = 'dia\\B'))
[1] "radial"    "diafragma"

str_subset(string = x, regex(pattern = '\\Bdia\\B'))
[1] "radial"
```

Como `\B` é o inverso de `\b` (assim como ocorre com `\w` e `\W`, `\s` e `\S` e assim por diante), o retorno foi o esperado, mas por conta de ser um exemplo simples.

Considere a situação a seguir. Tenho a variável:

```
y <- c('5203. ._2302', '4243424', '52033.23021', '5201w2211', '53210ggsd3333')
```

E o código:

```
str_subset(string = y, regex(pattern = '\\b5\\d{3}\\w'))
[1] "52033.23021"   "5201w2211"     "53210ggsd3333"
```

Que retorna tudo que comece com `5` seguido de `3` digitos com qualquer caracter `\\w` (`[A-Za-z0-9_`) em seguida. Ok.

O que não entendo são os códigos abaixo:

```
str_subset(string = y, regex(pattern = '\\b5\\d{3}\\w\\b'))
[1] "52033.23021"

str_subset(string = y, regex(pattern = '\\b5\\d{3}\\w\\B'))
[1] "5201w2211"     "53210ggsd3333"
```

Enquanto o primeiro código casa tudo aquilo que termina com `\w`, deveria casar tudo, não? E, o segundo, ao invés de casar, deveria negar tudo.

Isso é que não entendi.

Portanto,

- qual a diferença, referente à aplicação e ocasião de uso, de `\b` e `\B`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, vale esclarecer que o atalho `\b` (também conhecido como [*word boundary*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), algo como "fronteira entre palavras") é um *zero-length match* (ou um *match* de tamanho zero): ele não corresponde a um caractere, e sim a uma posição da string (mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110874/112052)). No caso, é uma posição que possui um caractere alfanumérico antes e não possui um caractere alfanumérico depois (ou vice versa).

Tanto que a regex `a\b` encontra um *match* na string `"a"` (pois o final da string também é uma posição que tem um caractere alfanumérico antes e não tem um depois, [veja](https://ideone.com/OfDiZb)).

Já o `\B` é qualquer posição da string que não seja um `\b`, ou seja, uma posição em que ambos os caracteres - antes e depois desta posição - são alfanuméricos (ou que ambos são não-alfanuméricos).

> Inclusive, este é um padrão comum em regex: muitos [atalhos](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) como o `\w`, `\d` e `\s` possuem suas "contrapartes negativas", que é basicamente a mesma letra, só que maiúscula: `\W` é "qualquer caractere que não seja `\w`", `\D` é "qualquer caractere que não seja `\d`",  etc. Sendo assim, `\B` é qualquer posição da string que não corresponde a `\b`.

---

Sendo assim, nos seus exemplos ambas as regex começam com `\\b5\\d{3}\\w`: temos um `\b` antes do dígito `5`, e como `5` é alfanumérico, então este `\b` só encontra um *match* se antes do `5` não há um caractere alfanumérico (ou seja, antes do `5` pode ter um caractere não-alfanumérico, ou o `5` pode estar no início da string). Depois do `5` temos 3 dígitos (`\d{3}`), seguido de `\w` (que é um [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) que considera letras, números ou `_`).

O que muda é o que tem depois do `\w`. No primeiro caso, temos `\b`. Como `\w` representa um caractere alfanumérico, então o `\b` verifica se o que tem depois é não-alfanumérico. Por isso ele só pega o `"52033.23021"`. Veja como esta string corresponde à regex:

```
   5  203    3     .23021
\b 5  \d{3}  \w  \b
```

O segundo `\b` corresponde à posição entre o `3` e o `.`: de fato é uma posição que possui um caractere alfanumérico antes e não tem um alfanumérico depois.

As demais strings não dão *match* pelos seguintes motivos:

- `'5203. ._2302'`: depois do `5` e dos 3 dígitos, há um ponto, que não corresponde a `\w`
- `'4243424'`: não tem o `5`
- `'5201w2211'`: tem o `5`, os 3 dígitos e a letra `w`, que corresponde a `\w`. Mas depois da letra `w` há o dígito `2`, então a posição entre a letra `w` e o dígito `2` não corresponde a `\b`.
- `'53210ggsd3333'`: tem o `5`, os 3 dígitos e o dígito `0`, que corresponde a `\w`. Mas depois do `0` há a letra `g`, então a posição entre o dígito `0` e a letra `g` não corresponde a `\b`.

---

Já a regex `'\\b5\\d{3}\\w\\B'` tem um `\B` no final, ou seja, é uma posição na qual antes e depois tem dois caracteres alfanuméricos (ou dois não-alfanuméricos). Por isso ela pega as strings `"5201w2211"` e `"53210ggsd3333"`:

```
   5  201    w     2211
\b 5  \d{3}  \w  \B

   5  321    0     ggsd3333
\b 5  \d{3}  \w  \B
```

O `\w` pega um caractere alfanumérico, e nesse caso o `\B` só vai dar *match* caso o caractere seguinte também seja alfanumérico. Repare acima que na primeira string deu certo porque o `\B` corresponde à posição entre a letra `w` e o dígito `2`, e na segunda string é a posição entre o dígito `0` e a letra `g`. E por isso ele não pega as demais strings:

- `'5203. ._2302'`: depois do `5` e dos 3 dígitos, há um ponto, que não corresponde a `\w`
- `'4243424'`: não tem o `5`
- `'52033.23021'`: tem o `5`, os 3 dígitos e o dígito `3`, que corresponde a `\w`. Mas depois do dígito `3` há um ponto, que não é alfanumérico. Sendo assim, a posição entre o `3` e o ponto não corresponde a `\B`.

---

Por fim, vale esclarecer uma confusão que você fez. `\b` não corresponde somente ao início ou final da string, e sim a **qualquer posição** da string que tenha um caractere alfanumérico antes e não tenha um depois (ou vice-versa). Ex:

```
x <- c('ele podia ter feito isso', 'que dia feliz', 'o diabo que te carregue', 'foi adiado para amanhã')

str_subset(string = x, regex(pattern = '\\bdia'))
[1] "que dia feliz"           "o diabo que te carregue"

str_subset(string = x, regex(pattern = 'dia\\b'))
[1] "ele podia ter feito isso" "que dia feliz"           

str_subset(string = x, regex(pattern = '\\bdia\\b'))
[1] "que dia feliz"
```

O primeiro caso (`\\bdia`) pega qualquer palavra que comece com "dia", o segundo caso (`dia\\b`) pega qualquer palavra que termine com "dia", e o terceiro caso (`\\bdia\\b`) pega exatamente a palavra "dia". Repare que essas palavras não precisam estar no início ou final da string.

Veja também que nenhuma das regex pega a palavra "adiado", pois as posições antes e depois de "dia" também são alfanuméricos e portanto não correspondem a `\b`.

Por fim, se quer marcar especificamente o início ou final da string, use os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`.