# Regex para procurar palavra dentro de tag com CDATA

Tags: java, regex, xml

Tenho um arquivo que contém as seguintes possibilidades de sequência de caracteres:

1º Caso: `<text><![CDATA[Casa]]></text>`

2º Caso: `<text><![CDATA[Qualquer texto que tenha Casa no meio]]></text>`

Estou tentando montar uma expressão regular para fazer um *replace* da palavra `Casa` por `Edifício`, mas estou com problema para montar tal expressão, tentei da seguinte forma:

```
String text = "<text><![CDATA[Casa]]></text>";
String regex = "(\\<text><![CDATA[\\(\\w+)(/Casa)(\\w+)(\\]]></text>))";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
```

Mas isso me retorna erro na compilação do *pattern*, será que é possível fazer um regex que me retorne esses dois casos?

Comment: Se vc quer só substituir "Casa" por "Edificio", um simples `.replace("casa", "edificio")` não resolve?

Comment: @Gustavo queria que fosse simples assim, tenho locais no mesmo arquivo que contem a palavra casa que não pode ser alterado.

Comment: Recomendo você dar uma olhada nos métodos `string.matches(Pattern)` e `string.regionMatches(int, String, int, int)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sugiro a seguinte expressão RegEx: `(?<=CDATA\[)(.*?)(?=\])`

Exemplo de implementação

```
    String casoUm = "<text><![CDATA[Casa]]></text>";
    String casoDois = "<text><![CDATA[Qualquer texto que tenha Casa no meio]]></text>";
    String regex = "(?<=CDATA\\[)(.*?)(?=\\])";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(casoUm);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(casoUm.replaceAll("Casa", "Edifício"));
    }

    matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(casoUm);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(casoDois.replaceAll("Casa", "Edifício"));
    }
```

Exemplo: [RegEx Exemplo](http://regexr.com/4q122)

Comment: Francisco, estou com uma duvida, vc consegue me dizer se é possível considerar o `<text>` no pattern?

Comment: Sim, possivelmente algo assim: **(?<=<text><!\[CDATA\[)(.*?)(?=\]\]><\/text>)**  `String regex = "(?<=<text><!\\[CDATA\\[)(.*?)(?=\\]\\]><\\/text>)";`

Answer (score 1):

Se você está lendo ou manipulando XML/HTML, é melhor usar *parsers* específicos, em vez de regex ([pois regex não é a melhor ferramenta para estes casos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)). Em Java, uma boa alternativa é usar a [biblioteca jsoup](https://jsoup.org/).

Além disso, estou me baseando nos comentários, em especial [neste](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/424950/procurar-palavra-com-regex#comment825032_424950), no qual você diz que "*tenho locais no mesmo arquivo que contém a palavra casa que não pode ser alterado*". Então estou assumindo que a substituição deve ser feita **somente** quando a palavra "Casa" está dentro de um `CDATA`, e este por sua vez está dentro da *tag* `text`. Em qualquer outro caso, não deve ser feita nenhuma substituição.

Sendo assim, com jsoup ficaria assim:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.CDataNode;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;


String texto = "<text><![CDATA[Casa]]></text><text><![CDATA[Qualquer texto que tenha Casa no meio]]></text>"
        + "<text>Texto com Casa mas não dentro de CDATA</text>"
        + "<text><![CDATA[Casamento]]></text>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(texto, "", Parser.xmlParser());

for (Element e : doc.select("text")) { // pegar todas as tags "text"
    for (Node node : e.childNodes()) { // verificar se tem CDATA
        if (node instanceof CDataNode) {
            // trocar por outro CDATA, contendo "Edifício" no lugar de "Casa"
            CDataNode cdata = (CDataNode) node;
            String novoTexto = cdata.getWholeText().replaceAll("\\bCasa\\b", "Edifício");
            cdata.replaceWith(new CDataNode(novoTexto));
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(doc);
```

Como eu só verifico as *tags* `text` que possuem `CDATA`, e só troco o texto nestes casos, o resultado é:

```xml
<text><![CDATA[Edifício]]>
</text>
<text><![CDATA[Qualquer texto que tenha Edifício no meio]]>
</text>
<text>
 Texto com Casa mas não dentro de CDATA
</text>
<text><![CDATA[Casamento]]>
</text>
```

O terceiro caso não foi substituído pois, apesar de ter a palavra "Casa", não está dentro de um `CDATA` (que é o critério que usei, mas de qualquer forma, se o critério for outro, não é difícil usar as funcionalidades do jsoup para verificar as condições que você precisar - algo bem mais difícil de verificar com regex, dependendo do que você precisa).

Repare que o quarto caso (um `CDATA` que contém a palavra "Casamento") não é substituído. **Esse é um *corner case* que a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/424986/112052) deixou passar** (no caso, o código que tem lá trocaria a palavra "Casamento" por "Edifíciomento" - [veja](https://ideone.com/kPLsU9)).

No meu código acima isso não acontece porque eu uso o marcador `\b` (conhecido como ["word boundary"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), algo como "fronteira entre palavras" - veja mais sobre ele [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/420506/112052)). Basicamente, o `\b` marca uma posição da string que possui um caractere alfanumérico antes e um não-alfanumérico depois (ou vice-versa), garantindo assim que só farei a substituição de "Casa" quando esta for uma palavra completa, e não parte de uma palavra.

Outro detalhe da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/424986/112052) é que ela verifica se existe um `CDATA`, mas depois faz o `replace` em toda a string (inclusive nos demais trechos que você deu a entender que não deveriam ser substituídos - [veja](https://ideone.com/t9j51l)). Então se tiver um `CDATA` com "Casa", mas também tiver "Casa" em outra parte da string que não deve ser substituída, ambas serão.

De qualquer forma, usar uma biblioteca específica evita o uso de regex, que não é a ferramenta mais adequada para este caso. Regex lida com texto sem levar em conta o formato ou semântica do mesmo, e XML/HTML possuem variações demais (mais do que uma expressão regular é capaz de detectar). Qualquer variação mínima no XML poderá exigir uma mudança - nem sempre trivial - na regex (como podemos ver [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/245947/112052) - o exemplo é em HTML, mas as mesmas considerações valem para XML).

Um caso típico é se a *tag* estiver dentro de um comentário (ou seja, entre `<!--` e `-->`). O jsoup consegue detectar esta situação e ignora os comentários, ou seja, não faz a substituição do trecho comentado. Já a solução da outra resposta não consegue detectar este caso (pois a regex só olha o `CDATA`, sem levar em conta o contexto no qual ela está) e acaba substituindo tudo. Claro que por ser comentário, talvez não faça diferença, mas este é somente um dos muitos casos possíveis no qual o *parser* é muito melhor do que a regex para detectar determinadas situações e não dar falsos positivos.