# Exercício: Substituição rápida

Tags: javascript, funções

Sua missão agora é criar uma função chamada `substituicaoRapida` que você recebe um texto, uma palavra para procurar e a palavra que substituirá a que você está procurando. A função deve retornar o texto com a palavra substituída.

Exemplo:

```
let textoNovo = substituicaoRapida('Boa tarde','tarde','noite');
console.log(textoNovo) //'Boa noite'
```

Ao chamar a função `substituicaoRapida("Olá, usuário!","usuário","Ana")` deve retornar "Olá, Ana!"

Como fiz:

```
function substituicaoRapida ( ){
let texto = "Boa tarde"
let palavra = "tarde"
let textoNovo = texto.replace("tarde", "noite")
console.log(texto + ", " + palavra + ", " + textoNovo)
return textoNovo
}
substituicaoRapida ( )
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] seu post e explicar o problema, descrevendo o que tentou e onde está a dificuldade atual, de preferência com um [mcve]. Estudar a postagem disponível neste link pode fazer uma diferença muito positiva no seu aproveitamento do site: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70)

Answer (score 1):

Para atender a situação solicitada, basta usar a função abaixo:

Nota: A função acima, apenas substitui a primeira ocorrência da string, logo ela não atenderá aos casos em que a palavra a ser substituída ocorra mais de uma vez na string.

```js
function substituicaoRapida(texto, procurar, substituir){
  return texto.replace(procurar, substituir);
}

let textoNovo = substituicaoRapida('Boa tarde','tarde','noite');
console.log(textoNovo) //'Boa noite'

let textoMaisOcorrencias = substituicaoRapida('Boa tarde? Sim, boa tarde!','tarde','noite');
console.log(textoMaisOcorrencias) //'Boa noite? Sim, boa tarde!'
```

Para atender a todas as ocorrências, utilize o método abaixo, que como o próprio nome diz, é menos performática do que o método anterior:

```js
   function substituicaoLenta(texto, procurar, substituir){
      return texto.split(procurar).join(substituir);
    }

    let textoNovo = substituicaoLenta('Boa tarde','tarde','noite');
    console.log(textoNovo) //'Boa noite'

    let textoMaisOcorrencias = substituicaoLenta('Boa tarde? Sim, boa tarde!','tarde','noite');
    console.log(textoMaisOcorrencias) //'Boa noite? Sim, boa tarde!'
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 1):

Um primeiro problema é que você declarou `function substituicaoRapida ( )`, ou seja, a função não recebe nenhum parâmetro. E dentro dela, você usa sempre o mesmo texto ("Boa tarde"), então não importa o que você passe para a função, ela sempre usará este texto.

Sendo assim, sua função deve receber os textos como parâmetros, em vez de ter sempre um texto fixo dentro dela:

```js
function substituicaoRapida(texto, antigo, novo) {
    return texto.replace(antigo, novo);
}

console.log(substituicaoRapida('Boa tarde!', 'tarde', 'noite')); // Boa noite!
console.log(substituicaoRapida('Olá, usuário!', 'usuário', 'Ana')); // Olá, Ana!
```

Assim, a função recebe o texto original, o trecho a ser substituído e o novo texto. Mas tem dois poréns:

O primeiro é que o `replace` só é feito uma vez. Então se tiver mais de uma ocorrência da palavra, somente a primeira é substituída:

```js
function substituicaoRapida(texto, antigo, novo) {
    return texto.replace(antigo, novo);
}

console.log(substituicaoRapida('Boa tarde! Já é tarde.', 'tarde', 'noite')); // Boa noite! Já é tarde.
```

O código acima imprime "Boa noite! Já é tarde.", pois somente a primeira ocorrência de "tarde" foi substituída por "noite".

O outro porém - que não está claro se é algo que deve ser considerado no seu código (se bem que nem o caso de substituir somente a primeira ocorrência está especificado, mas enfim) - é que o `replace` não leva em conta se o texto a ser substituído é de fato parte de uma palavra ou se deve ser somente uma palavra inteira. Ex:

```js
function substituicaoRapida(texto, antigo, novo) {
    return texto.replace(antigo, novo);
}

console.log(substituicaoRapida('Entardeceu', 'tarde', 'noite')); // Ennoiteceu
```

O código acima imprime "Ennoiteceu".

Enfim, caso queira levar em conta os 2 casos acima, basta usar uma expressão regular, usando [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```js
function substituicaoRapida(texto, antigo, novo) {
    return texto.replace(new RegExp(`\\b${antigo}\\b`, 'g'), novo);
}

console.log(substituicaoRapida('Boa tarde, é tarde. Entardeceu', 'tarde', 'noite')); // Boa noite, é noite. Entardeceu
```

O código acima imprime "Boa noite, é noite. Entardeceu" (as duas ocorrências de "tarde" foram substituídas por "noite", e "Entardeceu" não sofre substituição por não ser a palavra "tarde").

Basicamente, usei o [atalho `\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), que indica uma "fronteira entre palavras" (uma posição que contém um caractere alfanumérico antes e outro não-alfanumérico depois, ou vice versa), assim eu garanto que só pegará a palavra "tarde", e ignorará quando ela fizer parte de outra palavra (como em "Entardeceu"). Lembrando que por estar em uma string, o caractere `\` deve ser escrito como `\\`. [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/420506/112052) você pode ver mais detalhes sobre o `\b`.

Também uso a [*flag* `g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp#Parameters) (o segundo parâmetro no construtor de `RegExp`), que faz com que todas as ocorrências sejam substituídas (não somente a primeira).

Answer (score 0):

Note que ao retornar `textoNovo` o script finaliza sua execução retornando o novo valor da variável `textoNovo`, entretanto ele não faz nada com esse valor, não imprime no console.

Deste modo para imprimir esse novo valor no console ao fim do script use:

```js
function substituicaoRapida()
{
    let texto = "Boa tarde"
    let palavra = "tarde"
    let textoNovo = texto.replace("tarde", "noite")
    return console.log(textoNovo)
}
substituicaoRapida ( )
```

Answer (score 0):

Vamos entender o que a função **replace** faz?
a função recebe dois parâmetros o primeiro para busca e o segundo para substituição

```
let nome = "noite"
console.log(nome.replace("noite", "dia"))
```

**perceba que essa função não altera a variável original**

```
console.log(nome)
```

**assim devemos atribuir a outra ou a mesma variável**

```
nome = nome.replace("noite", "dia")
console.log(nome)
```

**Seu exercício:** Sua missão agora é criar uma função chamada "substituicaoRapida" que você recebe um texto, uma palavra 
para procurar e a palavra que substituirá a que você está procurando. A função deve retornar o texto com a palavra substituída.

a primeira opção de função e eu gosto mais dessa opção seria utilizado arow functions

```
let nomeAntigo = "nomeAntigo"
const trocaNomes = (nome, novoNome) => nome.replace(nome, novoNome)
nomeAntigo = trocaNomes(nomeAntigo, "nomeNovo")
console.log(nomeAntigo)
```

A segunda forma seria utilizando uma função mais convencional da linguagem

```
function substituicaoRapida() {
    let texto = "Boa tarde"
    let textoNovo = texto.replace("tarde", "noite")
    return (`${textoNovo}`)
}

console.log(substituicaoRapida('Boa tarde'))
```