# str_replace_all - como encontrar palavras pelas 3 primeiras letras de uma string?

Tags: r, string

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```r
library(stringr)

filtro_palavras <- structure(list(palavras = c("cultivo", "produtos", "atacadista", 
"papel", "madeira", "água", "agrícola", "vestuário", "calçados", 
"fumo", "agricultura", "bebidas", "agropecuária", "florestas", 
"abate")), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Gostaria de substituir as palavras que começam com "agr" (no caso: agrícola,cagricultura,cagropecuária) por agr.

Para isso, estou tentando o seguinte:

```
filtro_palavras$palavras <- str_replace_all(filtro_palavras$palavras, "^agr", "agr")
```

Mas não acontece nenhuma alteração.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é necessário carregar um pacote externo para fazer essa substituição, o R base tem funções `sub` e `gsub` que resolvem o problema.

```
sub("^agr.*\\b", "agr.", filtro_palavras$palavras)
# [1] "cultivo"    "produtos"   "atacadista" "papel"     
# [5] "madeira"    "água"       "agr."       "vestuário" 
# [9] "calçados"   "fumo"       "agr."       "bebidas"   
#[13] "agr."       "florestas"  "abate"
```

**Explicação da regex**

1. `"^"` Início da string.
2. `"^agr"` a string começa por `"agr"`.
3. `"^agr.*" a string começada por` "agr"` é seguida por zero ou mais carateres.
4. `"^agr.*\\b"` a string do ponto acima está limitada por fronteira de palavra. Em vez de `\\b` que pode ser usado em ambos os lados da palavra, neste caso também pode ser `\\>` (só no fim da palavra).

Comment: Interessante!  Pode explicar melhor o que seria `fronteira de palavra` e o `\\b`? Obrigado!

Comment: @RxT Existe uma explicação sobre o `\b` [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/420506/112052)

Comment: @hkotsubo Ou [aqui](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html), no parágrafo antes de *"A regular expression may be followed by one of several repetition quantifiers"*.

Answer (score 0):

Entendi o que estava errado.

O símbolo `^` indica *apenas* que a palavra deve começar com essas letras.

Faltou o simbolo `.` que indica qualquer caractere e o símbolo `+` que indica repetições do último caractere (no caso, `.`).

Então, para pegar as três primeiras letras ficou assim:

```
filtro_palavras$palavras <- str_replace_all(filtro_palavras$palavras, '^agr.+', 'agr')
```

Traduzindo: começa com "agr", depois pode vir qualquer caractere, infinitas vezes.