# Regex para números de diferentes tamanhos

Tags: regex, r, stringr

Preciso ler uma imagem .png com uma tabela de movimentação financeira, como a debaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desta tabela preciso extrair as colunas saldo bruto, disponibilidades, Aplicacao/Resgate e Saldo Bruto Final. Pois, preciso identificar a entrada e saída de movimentações financeiras de cada conta. Estou usando o pacote `tesseract` para realizar o `ocr` e isolar somente os fundos de investimento.

```
library(tesseract)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tabulizer)
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

caminho <- "...\\04 - APR - Processo SEI\\2020\\10 - Outubro\\15-10"

str_detect("FP")
arquivo <- paste(caminho,list.files(caminho)[str_detect(list.files(caminho), "FP")], sep = "/")

txt <- ocr(arquivo)

cnpj <- "\\d{2}[.]\\d{3}[.]\\d{3}[/]\\d{4}[-]\\d{2}"

empilhadoi <- txt %>% map(as_tibble) %>% 
                # empilha
                bind_rows()

empilhado <- as.data.frame(str_split(txt, fixed("\n"))[[1]])

empilhado <- as.data.frame(empilhado[-1,])
```

O meu desafio esta em separar os valores das colunas; `saldo bruto`, `disponibilidades`, `Aplicacao/Resgate` e `Saldo Bruto Final`. Fiz a seguinte regex `str_extract_all(empilhado$`empilhado[-1, ]`, "-?R\\$\\d{0,3}[.?,?]\\d{0,3}[.?,?]\\d{0,3}")`, mas, ela só funciona para os números no formato R$999.999.999,99. Porém, meus números podem variar de 0-999.999.999,99 - e para negativo tbm. Como nesta tabela temos o -R$23.991,56, ele não detecta. Estou utilizando o `Rstudio` com linguagem R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta fazer com que a parte dos milhares seja opcional:

```
str_extract_all(empilhado$`empilhado[-1, ]`, "-?R\\$\\d{1,3}([.,]\\d{3})*[.,]\\d{2}")
```

Ou seja, o trecho `([.,]\\d{3})` (ponto ou vírgula seguido de exatamente 3 dígitos) pode se repetir zero ou mais vezes - a repetição é indicada pelo [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`. Assim a regex pega valores menores que 1000 também. Deixei `{3}` para que sejam exatamente 3 dígitos, pois `{0,3}` pega entre zero e 3 dígitos, mas entendo que entre os separadores de milhares sempre têm 3 dígitos.

E como o maior valor é `999.999.999`, você poderia trocar o `*` por `{0,2}` (já que a sequência "ponto/vírgula + 3 dígitos" pode se repetir no máximo 2 vezes).

E para o primeiro dígito após o "R$" mudei para `\\d{1,3}` (entre 1 e 3 dígitos), pois acho que aí deve ter pelo menos um.

Na parte dos centavos troquei por `\\d{2}`, pois ali entendo que só podem ter exatamente 2 dígitos.

Troquei a vírgula ou ponto apenas por `[.,]`, pois ao colocar a interrogação dentro dos colchetes faz com que a regex também pegue o caractere `?`. Se a ideia era deixar o ponto ou a vírgula opcional, basta trocar para `[.,]?`.

---

Outro detalhe é que esta expressão aceita valores como "R$000.000,00". Se for para não aceitar estes casos, pode trocar para:

```
str_extract_all(x, "\\b-?R\\$(0|[1-9]\\d{0,2}([.,]\\d{3}){0,2})[.,]\\d{2}\\b")
```

Eu uso [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`, que significa "ou"). Assim, antes dos centavos pode ter apenas um zero, ou um dígito de 1 a 9 (`[1-9]`) seguido de zero a 2 dígitos (garantindo que podem ter valores de 1 a 999).

Também coloquei `\\b` para garantir que antes e depois não hajam outros caracteres alfanuméricos (ou seja, para garantir que os valores estejam "isolados" no texto). [Leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/420487/112052) para entender melhor.

Comment: Vlw, vou estudar sua regex para ver se compreendo o que vc fez!

Comment: @FlavioSilva Fiz uma alteração para os centavos e coloquei também outra opção para limitar melhor os valores