# Como acessar a posição de múltiplos matchs de um regex em uma string?

Tags: python, regex

Eu sei que posso acessar a posição de um match de um regex em uma string usando os métodos `start`, `end` e `span`. Exemplo de um programa que identifica repetições em um texto:

```py
import re
from colorama import Fore,Style

text='''Dorsey was born and raised in St. Louis, Missouri,[8][9] 
the son of Tim and Marcia (née Smith) Dorsey.[10][11][12] He is of English, Irish, and Italian descent.[13] 
His father worked for a company that developed mass spectrometers and his mother was a homemaker.[14] 
He was raised Catholic, and his uncle is a Catholic Catholic priest in Cincinnati.[15] He attended the Catholic 
Bishop DuBourg High School. In his younger days, Dorsey worked occasionally as a fashion model.
[16][17][18][19][20] By age 14, Dorsey had become interested in dispatch dispatch routing. Some of the open-source software he created in the area of dispatch logistics is still used by taxicab companies.[10] Dorsey enrolled at the University of Missouri–Rolla in 1995 and attended for two-plus years[15] before transferring to New York University in 1997, but he dropped out two years later,[21] one semester short of graduating.[15] 
He came up with the idea that he developed as Twitter while studying at NYU.[15][22]
'''

print("Searching for repeated words ...", "\n")
try:
    result=re.search(r'(\w{3,}\s)\1',text)
    start=result.start()
    end=result.end()
    value=result.group()
    print("The word \"{}\" is repeated at: ".format(value.split(' ')[0]),"\n\n")

    print(text[start-100:start]+ Fore.RED + text[start:end]+ Style.RESET_ALL+text[end:end+200])
except:
    print("No repeated words found")
```

Retorna:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que o problema desse programa é que ele identifica apenas uma ocorrência. Eu imaginei que o método `start` retornaria uma lista ou tuple quando existe mais de um match, mas não é isso que acontece.

Como posso acessar a posição de todos os matchs de uma expressão regular em uma string? Por exemplo, a palavra *dispatch* também se repete no texto, mas não sei como faço para pegar a posição dela.

Comment: Não diretamente relacionado, mas quando  `search` não encontra nada ele retorna `None`, então em vez de `try`/`except`, bastaria fazer `if result: encontrou else: não encontrou`

Comment: Só palavras repetidas consecutivamente ex: `Catholic Catholic` e `dispatch dispatch` ou todas as palavras repetidas ex: `Dorsey`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você está utilizando a função `re.search` para fazer o *match* da expressão regular. De acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search):

> Escaneia através da string procurando pela **primeira** posição onde a expressão regular produz um *match* e retorna o *match object* correspondente. [...]

Portanto, como a função `search` (assim como `match` e `fullmatch`) permitem apenas *uma* busca, você deve utilizar outra função, que permita realizar **múltiplas buscas** sucessivas em uma string.

O Python fornece as funções `re.findall` `re.finditer` para realizar a busca "completa", indo além da primeira ocorrência se presente. De modo que:

- [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) retorna todos os *matches* sem sobreposição como uma lista de strings.
- [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) retorna um iterador que produz *match objects* para cada *match* na string.

Como o seu código utiliza métodos presentes em [*match objects*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects), `finditer` me parece mais ideal.

Observe que como `finditer` retorna um *iterador*, é necessário utilizar algum tipo de meio para iterar sobre cada *match objeto* por ele produzido. No caso da string não tiver fornecido nenhum *match*, o iterador será vazio, de modo que nenhuma iteração ocorrerá.

No exemplo da pergunta, seria algo como:

```
import re
from colorama import Fore, Style

text = '''Dorsey was born and raised in St. Louis, Missouri,[8][9]
the son of Tim and Marcia (née Smith) Dorsey.[10][11][12] He is of English, Irish, and Italian descent.[13]
His father worked for a company that developed mass spectrometers and his mother was a homemaker.[14]
He was raised Catholic, and his uncle is a Catholic Catholic priest in Cincinnati.[15] He attended the Catholic
Bishop DuBourg High School. In his younger days, Dorsey worked occasionally as a fashion model.
[16][17][18][19][20] By age 14, Dorsey had become interested in dispatch dispatch routing. Some of the open-source software he created in the area of dispatch logistics is still used by taxicab companies.[10] Dorsey enrolled at the University of Missouri–Rolla in 1995 and attended for two-plus years[15] before transferring to New York University in 1997, but he dropped out two years later,[21] one semester short of graduating.[15]
He came up with the idea that he developed as Twitter while studying at NYU.[15][22]
'''

print("Searching for repeated words ...", "\n")

all_matches_iter = re.finditer(r'(\w{3,}\s)\1', text)

for match in all_matches_iter:
    start = match.start()
    end = match.end()
    value = match.group()

    print("The word \"{}\" is repeated at: ".format(
        value.split(' ')[0]), "\n\n")
    print(text[start-100:start] + Fore.RED +
          text[start:end] + Style.RESET_ALL+text[end:end+200])
```

Answer (score 3):

Apenas para dar outra alternativa (pois o que eu usaria mesmo é `finditer`, conforme a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/502920/112052) já explicou).

Você pode usar `search` indicando a posição em que a busca deve começar, e fazer um loop até que não haja mais *matches*:

```
import re

r = re.compile(r'(\w{3,}\s)\1')
end = 0
print("Searching for repeated words ...", "\n")
while True:
    result = r.search(text, end)
    if not result: break # se não achou, sai do while
    start = result.start()
    end = result.end()
    value=result.group()
    # o resto é igual (print, etc)
```

Repare que cada busca começa na posição em que a anterior termina (exceto pela primeira, que parte do início da string).

Curiosamente, esta opção de passar a posição inicial como parâmetro só está disponível para o [método da classe `Pattern`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search) (que é o que `compile` retorna), mas não na [função `re.search` do módulo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search).

---

Aproveitando, sua regex pode ser melhorada pois ela tem alguns problemas.

Por exemplo, se o texto tiver algo como `"Não seria ria etc..."`, o trecho `"ria ria"` será encontrado (o primeiro "ria" é da palavra "seria").

E se tiver algo como `"etc etc."`, ele não é encontrado, pois você colocou o espaço dentro do grupo de captura, então `\1` só vai encontrar a palavra se também tiver um espaço depois.

Para arrumar isso, a regex deveria ser: `r'(\b\w{3,}\b)\s\1'` - no caso, o `\b` serve para delimitar a palavra (leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/420487/112052) para mais detalhes) e coloquei o espaço fora dos parênteses (assim, `result.group()` retornará a palavra sem o espaço - no seu código, está retornando com o espaço depois, não sei se era essa a intenção).

Vale lembrar que `\w` pega não só letras, mas também dígitos e o caractere `_`. Se quiser somente letras (incluindo as acentuadas), pode trocar para `r'(\b[^\W\d_]{3,}\b)\s\1'`.

Comment: Essa parte da posição de onde deve começar provavelmente (não confirmei) deve ajudar um pouco (ou muito) em performance, prometo lhes devolver um benchmark comparando em um exemplo bem mais simples isso e o finditer.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Fiz um teste básico com `timeit` e não houve diferença significativa (às vezes `finditer` é ligeiramente mais rápido, às vezes não, na prática deu empate técnico): https://replit.com/@hkotsubo/RegexSearchVsFindIter#main.py | https://ideone.com/jYfS14 - Acredito que em muitos casos não fará diferença mesmo, **talvez** um caso ou outro dependendo da string e/ou da regex possa fazer diferença.