# Montar lista sem palavras repetidas a partir de um arquivo

Tags: python

Estou tentando criar um programa que leia um arquivo de texto `.txt` e transforme cada linha em uma lista. Depois, com essas listas, o programa gera uma nova lista com as palavras das listas anteriores, sem repetições de palavras e em ordem alfabética.

```py
arq = open(''arquivo.txt'')

count = 0

x = 0

for contador in arq:

         count = count + 1

else:
   
      while x<= count:
           
        linha = arq.readline()

        a = linha.split()
 
        x = x + 1

        print(a)
```

Esse foi o que tentei. Mas quando vou rodar o programa, só aparecem quatro listas vazias. O arquivo que utilizei tem quatro linhas.

Answer (score 3):

Uma alternativa é guardar as palavras em um [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set), que é uma estrutura nativa que não permite repetições. Assim, basta ler o arquivo, ler as linhas do mesmo, separar as palavras de cada linha e ir guardando-as em um `set`:

```
palavras = set()
with open('arquivo.txt') as arq:
    for linha in arq: # para cada linha do arquivo
        for palavra in linha.split(' '): # para cada palavra da linha
            palavras.add(palavra) # adiciona a palavra no set

palavras_em_ordem = sorted(palavras)
print(palavras_em_ordem)
```

Ao adicionar a palavra, o próprio `set` verifica se ela já existe, e não adicionará palavras duplicadas. Em seguida, basta usar [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) para obter a lista das palavras ordenadas.

Repare que eu abri o arquivo dentro de um `with`, que [garante que o arquivo é fechado ao final](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/112052), mesmo em caso de erro durante a leitura ou o processamento das linhas. O `for linha in arq` faz com que seja lida uma linha de cada vez (usar `readlines`, como sugeriu a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/447148/112052), carrega todo o conteúdo do arquivo para a memória de uma vez, o que pode consumir recursos desnecessariamente se o arquivo for muito grande).

Vale lembrar também que a solução da outra resposta pode ser tornar bem mais lenta conforme a lista de palavras cresce, já que para cada palavra é feito um teste para saber se ela já está na lista, e esse teste em listas é mais lento se comparado com *sets* ([faça aqui o teste](https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/DarkseagreenLooseMicrobsd#main.py)).

---

Por fim, vale lembrar que fazer o `split` por espaço é uma solução "ingênua" para obter as palavras. Não ficou claro o que tem no arquivo, mas se tiver uma frase como "Olá, tudo bem?", o `split(' ')` vai considerar que `Olá,` e `bem?` são palavras (a vírgula e a interrogação farão parte da "palavra", então elas serão consideradas palavras diferentes de `Olá` e `bem`). Se quiser considerar casos mais complexos e eliminar vírgulas, sinais de pontuação, e também considerar palavras compostas (como "beija-flor") ou com apóstrofo ("gota d'água"), há alguns exemplos [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/450163/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348269/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401529/112052).

Também não é feita distinção entre maiúsculas e minúsculas: `oi` e `Oi` são consideradas palavras diferentes. Se quer considerar que ambas são a mesma palavra, basta mudar a linha que adiciona no `set` para `palavras.add(palavra.casefold())`.

Comment: a observação de abrir o arquivo com a função `with`, foi bastante oportuna. Pois todas as vezes em que trabalhamos com arquivos, devemos garantir o seu carregamento, bem como o seu encerramento.  Boa observação. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Se entendi bem o seu problema, aqui o que voce esta tentando fazer:

```
arquivo = open('myfile.txt', 'r') 
listaDeLinhas = arquivo.readlines() 

palavras = [] 
for linha in listaDeLinhas:
     conteudoLinha = linha.split(" ")
     for palavra in conteudoLinha:
         if palavra not in palavras:
             palavras.append(palavra)
```

algo assim

Comment: Sim, era isso mesmo. Olhando assim parece ser tão simples, mas tentei de tantas maneiras. Minha dificuldade com a programação está sendo enxergar a conexão com os códigos. Eu tenho a ideia de como o programa funciona, mas na hora de passar isso para os comandos da linguagem, não funciona.