# Como obter a primeira palavra de um texto em Python?

Tags: python, string, split

```
frase = str("Eu como abacaxi").split()
```

Como eu faço para mostrar apenas a primeira palavra da frase ("eu" no caso)?

Comment: Não seria frase[0]?

Comment: [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) retorna uma lista, então basta pegar o primeiro elemento dela com `frase[0]`, como já disseram. Outro detalhe é que usar `str` em uma string é redudante e desnecessário, pode fazer apenas `"Eu como abacaxi".split()`

Comment: Ou apenas `first, rest = frase.split(maxsplit=1)`, mas isso não resolve o problema se houver pontuação, por exemplo, tal como em `frase = 'eu, eu mesmo e irene'`, a primeira palavra seria `'eu,'`, com a vírgula

Comment: @Woss Ainda bem que "[*There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)", né? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz

```py
primeira_palavra = str("Eu como abacaxi").split()[0]
```

O método `split()` vai quebrar a string pelo separador informado, como não informou ele vai quebrar pelo espaço.

Depois de quebrar ele retorna uma lista assim `['Eu', 'como', 'abacaxi']`

Daí você pode usar o índice zero para pegar o primeiro elemento, que será então a primeira palavra.

Answer (score 3):

A forma de fazer depende muito de como está sua string e do que você considera como "palavra".

---

No seu caso específico, basta pegar o primeiro elemento da lista retornada por [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
frase = "Eu como abacaxi".split()
primeira_palavra = frase[0]

# ou simplesmente
primeira_palavra = "Eu como abacaxi".split()[0]
```

Detalhe: quando você tem um texto entre aspas no código, [ele já é uma string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings), então é redundante e desnecessário fazer `str("texto")`, pois `"texto"` já é uma string.

---

## Limitações

A solução acima é bem limitada, pois como já apontaram [nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/449990/como-obter-a-primeira-palavra-de-um-texto-em-python#comment862078_449990), se a frase tiver alguma pontuação, já não funciona mais:

```
primeira_palavra = "Eu, você e ele comemos abacaxi".split()[0]
print(primeira_palavra) # Eu,
```

Nesse caso, a primeira palavra acaba sendo `Eu,` - a vírgula faz parte da "palavra". E é aí que devemos definir o que exatamente é uma palavra (não pode ser "qualquer coisa que não seja espaço", pois é isso que você está considerando ao chamar `split` sem nenhum parâmetro).

E o primeiro elemento também pode não ser uma palavra (ex: se a string for `"- lorem ipsum"`, a primeira "palavra" será o hífen).

Uma solução é considerar que palavras são apenas "sequências de letras consecutivas". Neste caso, bastaria usar o método [`isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) para verificar os caracteres da string que são letras:

```
frase = " - 123... Eu, você e ele comemos abacaxi!"
inicio = fim = None
for i, c in enumerate(frase):
    letra = c.isalpha()
    if inicio is None and letra:
        inicio = i # início de palavra
    elif inicio is not None and fim is None and not letra:
        fim = i # fim de palavra
        break # sai do loop
else: # chegou ao fim da string e não encontrou um caractere que não é letra
    fim = len(frase)

if inicio is not None and fim is not None:
    primeira_palavra = frase[inicio:fim]
    print(primeira_palavra)
else:
    print('A frase não contém nenhuma palavra')
```

Eu uso [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para iterar pelos caracteres da string e pelos seus respectivos índices. A cada iteração do `for`, a variável `c` será um dos caracteres da string, e `i` será o seu respectivo índice.

Inicialmente eu busco pelo primeiro caractere que é uma letra para encontrar o índice inicial. A partir daí vou avançando até encontrar um caractere que não é uma letra, indicando que a palavra já terminou, e nesse caso eu guardo o índice final e encerro o *loop* com `break`.

Repare que tem um `else` que pertence ao `for`. Ele é chamado se o `for` **não** for interrompido por um `break`, o que nesse caso indica que cheguei ao final da string sem encontrar um caractere que não é letra (ou seja, ou não tem nenhuma palavra, ou a única palavra da string termina justamente no final da mesma). Neste caso, pegamos tudo até o fim da string.

Depois do `for` verificamos se a string tem ou não uma palavra, e se tiver, pegamos a primeira, usando os índices encontrados previamente (usando a [sintaxe de *slicing*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211) para pegar o trecho da string entre os índices inicial e final).

Esta solução trata os casos em que a string inteira é uma única palavra, além dos casos em que ela não tem nenhuma palavra (ela pode ser por exemplo "123", ou "@!#").

---

#### Palavras compostas

Só há um porém: a solução anterior não considera palavras compostas, como por exemplo "beija-flor" (já que o hífen não é uma letra e `isalpha` retorna `False` para este caractere).

Você poderia adaptar o código acima para aceitar hífen, desde que os caracteres imediatamente antes e depois sejam letras. Mas há outra alternativa, que é usar expressões regulares (regex), através do [módulo `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

frase = " - 123... Beija-flor, come abacaxi!"
regex = re.compile(r'\b[^\W\d_]+(-[^\W\d_]+)*\b')
match = regex.search(frase)
if match:
    primeira_palavra = match.group()
    print(primeira_palavra) # Beija-flor
else:
    print('A frase não contém nenhuma palavra')
```

Para a palavra, muitos provavelmente usariam o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w`, que realmente considera todas as letras. Só que ele também considera dígitos e o caractere `_`. Se você quer que não considere "123" e "abc_def" como palavras, temos que excluir os dígitos e o `_` da expressão.

Para isso usamos uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated): `[^\W\d_]+`. No caso, é tudo que **não** é `\W`, nem `\d`, e nem `_`. O `\W` é o oposto de `\w` (ou seja, tudo que não é letra, número e nem `_`). Então tudo que não é `\W` é o mesmo que `\w`, só que também estou excluindo os dígitos (`\d`) e o próprio `_`. Assim, sobram só letras.

No fundo é uma forma de dizer que só quero letras - e este atalho é melhor do que `[a-zA-Z]` porque também considera letras acentuadas. E o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` pega uma ou mais ocorrências.

Depois temos um trecho contendo hífen e uma ou mais letras, e esse trecho pode ocorrer zero ou mais vezes (indicado pelo `*`). Assim cobrimos os casos em que há mais de um hífen (como "pão-de-ló" - *se bem que depois da reforma ortográfica acho que não tem mais hífen, mas enfim*).

Tudo isso está envolto pelo [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`, que indica uma ["fronteira entre palavras"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/420487/112052) (uma posição que possui um caractere alfanumérico antes e um não-alfanumérico depois), senão em casos como "12abc34", a regex consideraria que "abc" é uma palavra.

Assim, palavras compostas também são consideradas.

---

Claro que - sempre - dá para complicar mais. E palavras com apóstrofo? (como "olho-d'água"). Nesse caso temos que incluir `(\'[^\W\d_]+)?` na regex (um apóstrofo seguido por uma ou mais letras, e o `?` indica que todo esse trecho é [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)):

```
regex = re.compile(r'\b[^\W\d_]+(\'[^\W\d_]+)?(-[^\W\d_]+(\'[^\W\d_]+)?)*\b')
```

---

#### Unicode

Sempre dá para complicar mais. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
import re

frase = "sábio da montanha"
regex = re.compile(r'\b[^\W\d_]+(\'[^\W\d_]+)?(-[^\W\d_]+(\'[^\W\d_]+)?)*\b')
match = regex.search(frase)
if match:
    primeira_palavra = match.group()
    print(primeira_palavra)
else:
    print('A frase não contém nenhuma palavra')
```

O resultado é:

```
sa
```

O que aconteceu é que a string `"sábio da montanha"` está em NFD (uma das [formas de normalização definidas pelo Unicode](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/)). Basicamente, a letra `á` ("a" com acento agudo) é decompostas em dois caracteres: a letra "a" sem acento e o [próprio acento](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301/index.htm) (só que visualmente não dá para distinguir, pois sempre é mostrado como `á`). Como o caractere referente ao acento não é uma letra, ele não é considerado parte da palavra (tem uma explicação mais detalhada sobre a normalização [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406545/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/396555/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/345946/112052) - apesar dos links não falarem especificamente sobre o Python, a ideia é a mesma).

Uma opção é normalizar para NFC (usando o [módulo `unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html)), pois assim os caracteres "a" e o acento são condensados em um único caractere (o `á`), e este passa a ser considerado como uma letra pela regex:

```
frase = "sábio da montanha"

from unicodedata import normalize
frase = normalize('NFC', frase)
... etc (o resto é igual)
```

Assim, a palavra "sábio" é encontrada pela regex.

---

#### Alternativa: módulo `regex`

Se quiser, pode instalar o [módulo `regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), uma excelente extensão do módulo `re`. Com ele você pode usar as [*Unicode properties*](https://pypi.org/project/regex/#unicode-codepoint-properties-including-scripts-and-blocks). Isso porque nem todas as strings em NFC terão o caractere do acento "aglutinado" com a letra, então a solução acima que usa normalização nem sempre funcionará.

Neste caso, usamos `\p{L}\p{M}*` para uma "letra" (`\p{L}` é qualquer caractere que o Unicode define como "letra" e `\p{M}` engloba os caracteres como o acento e outros que podem ser aplicados à uma letra - os chamados *combining characters*). Você pode consultar a lista completa [nesta página](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm) (`\p{L}` engloba todas as categorias que começam com "L" e `\p{M}`, todas que começam com "M").

Sendo assim, ficaria:

```
import regex
r = regex.compile(r'\b(\p{L}\p{M}*)+(\'(\p{L}\p{M}*)+)?(-(\p{L}\p{M}*)+(\'(\p{L}\p{M}*)+)?)*\b')

# restante do código igual
match = r.search(frase)
etc...
```

---

Enfim, veja como a solução pode se complicar, dependendo do que você considera "palavra". E estamos nos limitando apenas à definição do português, já que há idiomas (como o japonês e chinês) em que você pode ter frases inteiras sem nenhum espaço entre as palavras (`\p{L}` até considera letras desses alfabetos, mas se não tiver espaços na frase, aí provavelmente você teria que usar soluções específicas para cada idioma - [exemplo](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11687) - e se quiser se limitar apenas ao nosso alfabeto, pode trocar `\p{L}` por `\p{Script=Latin}`).

Claro que para textos mais simples como o seu, talvez o `split` já resolva (desde que você também trate o caso da string ser vazia (`""`), pois aí `split` retorna uma lista vazia e dará erro ao tentar acessar o primeiro elemento - coisa que não acontece com as outras soluções, que identificam corretamente que não há nenhuma palavra). Mas achei que valia a pena expandir um pouco o problema de "encontrar a primeira palavra de um texto" para casos não tão óbvios assim.