# Gostaria de fazer um código que soletrasse a palavra?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loop, while

Sou novo na programação e estou tentando montar um script no qual digito uma palavra e ele soletra ela para mim!

Eu montei o seguinte código!

```
nome = input('palavra para soletrar:')

while True :
    print('a primeira letra é',nome[0],'!')
    print('a segunda letra é',nome[1],'!')
    print('a terceira letra é',nome[2],'!')
    print('a quarta letra é',nome[3],'!')
    print('a quinta letra é',nome[4],'!')
    nome = input('palavra para soletrar:')
```

Só que quando a palavra é menor, o código para! Estou querendo montar um maior e que quando eu for colocar uma palavra com menos de 4 letras ele soletre ela do mesmo jeito e repita o código!

Comment: Não fixe a quantidade de letras, varie de acordo com a quantidade de letras da palavra fornecida.

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu seu problema, podes `aceitá-la`, clicando em `V` ao lado da resposta. [Veja aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta) porque aceitar. Apesar de não ser obrigatório, esta prática é estimulada no site, indicando a futuros visitantes que tal resposta resolveu o problema. E quando tiveres 15 pontos, [também poderás votar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em quaisquer respostas que jugares úteis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para você soletrar uma palavra você pode implementar o seguinte algoritmo:

1. Captura uma palavra;
2. Implementa um laço de repetição;
3. Em cada interação do laço exibe a posição e a referida letra;
4. Pergunta se deseja continuar.

Com esta lógica implementei o seguinte código:

```
while True:
    nome = input('Palavra para soletrar: ')

    cont = 0
    for letra in nome:
        cont += 1
        print(f'A {cont}ª letra é: {letra}')
    print()
    resp = input('Dsejas continuar? [S/N] ').upper()
    while (len(resp) != 1) or (resp not in 'SN'):
        print('Valor INVÁLIDO?')
        resp = input('Dsejas continuar? [S/N] ').upper()
    if resp == 'N':
        break
```

Observe que quando executamos o código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite uma palavra:` . Neste momento devemos digitar uma palavra. Em seguida, o laço de repetição `for` irá percorrer a string `palavra` e exibirá a **posição** e a **letra**. Depois nos perguntará se desejamos continuar. E caso digitarmos a letra `S`, o código será reexecutado. Caso digitarmos a letra `N`, o código será encerrado.

Answer (score 0):

Se quer iterar pelos caracteres de uma string e ao mesmo tempo obter a posição de cada um, basta usar [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). De forma resumida, ficaria:

```
palavra = input('palavra para soletrar:')
for i, letra in enumerate(palavra, start=1):
    print(f'A {i}ª letra é {letra}')
```

Assim, a cada iteração, `letra`  será um dos caracteres da string e `i` será a respectiva posição. Só que por padrão, `enumerate` começa a contagem dos índices em zero, mas eu posso indicar um valor inicial diferente passando o argumento `start`.

---

E no seu caso você está fazendo um *loop* para pedir várias palavras, e dá para melhorar um pouco. Por exemplo, não precisa colocar um `input` antes do `while` e outro dentro dele. Se você precisar por exemplo mudar a mensagem do `input` ou algo assim, terá que mudar em 2 lugares. Então faça tudo apenas uma vez, dentro do *loop*.

E como é um *loop* infinito, seria interessante ter alguma condição de parada. Por exemplo, se a palavra digitada for vazia (o usuário só digita um <kbd>ENTER</kbd>), você poderia encerrar o `while`:

```
while True:
    palavra = input('palavra para soletrar:')
    if not palavra: # se não foi digitado nada
        break # sai do while
    print(f'soletrando "{palavra}"')
    for i, letra in enumerate(palavra, start=1):
        print(f'A {i}ª letra é {letra}')
```

Claro que você pode usar qualquer lógica que quiser para interromper o programa (como o exemplo dado na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/476324/112052)). Mas o ponto principal é que você não precisa repetir o `input` fora e dentro do *loop*.

---

E se quiser que a saída tenha os números ordinais por extenso, uma alternativa é instalar o [módulo `num2words`](https://pypi.org/project/num2words/):

```
from num2words import num2words

while True:
    palavra = input('palavra para soletrar:')
    if not palavra:
        break
    print(f'soletrando "{palavra}"')
    for i, letra in enumerate(palavra, start=1):
        print(f'O {num2words(i, to="ordinal", lang="pt_BR")} caractere é {letra}')
```

O problema é que o `num2words` não possui opção para os números ordinais no feminino (ele só retorna "primeiro" e não há opção para retornar "primeira"). Então o jeito é fazer a gambiarra:

```
def ordinal_fem(i):
    s = num2words(i, to="ordinal", lang="pt_BR")
    return s[:-1] + 'a' # troca a última letra por "a"
```

Aí no *loop* basta usar a função acima:

```
for i, letra in enumerate(palavra, start=1):
    print(f'A {ordinal_fem(i)} letra é {letra}')
```

Ou você pode procurar por outras libs que tratam esses casos (em uma busca rápida, encontrei [esta](https://github.com/aricaldeira/pybrasil), mas não cheguei a testar).

Vale lembrar também que `input` aceita qualquer coisa que for digitada pelo usuário, podendo inclusive ser uma frase com várias palavras, ou somente espaços ou coisas que não necessariamente são palavras (como `123`, `!@#$%`, etc). Claro que aí já foge do escopo da pergunta, mas se quiser material adicional sobre o assunto, pode dar uma olhada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/450163/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348269/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401529/112052).