# Qual a melhor maneira de verificar se uma string tem alguma dessas palavras?

Tags: python, string

Tenho uma dúvida, considerem o seguinte:

```
nomes_proibidos = ['Corona', 'Clorivaldo', 'Pfizernaldo', 'Hulk', 'Naruto', 'Goku', 'Cloroquina']

def verificar_nome(n):
    for nome in nomes_proibidos:
        if n.find(nome) != -1:
            return False

    return True

verificar_nome('Pedro Hulk da Silva')
```

Existe uma melhor maneira de fazer isso? Estou precisando fazer algo semelhante, só que com uma lista de palavras muito maior e estou preocupado com o desempenho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma alternativa é usar [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) para quebrar a string em palavras, e ver se cada uma das palavras está na lista:

```
def verificar_nome(frase):
    for palavra in frase.split():
        if palavra in nomes_proibidos:
            return False
    return True
```

Esta solução é "ingênua" porque qualquer frase um pouco mais complicada já quebra o algoritmo. Por exemplo, se a frase for `Oi, tudo bem?`, as "palavras" serão `Oi,` (com a vírgula), `tudo` e `bem?` (com a interrogação), então se "Oi" estivesse na lista de palavras proibidas, ela não seria encontrada.

Então no fundo, precisamos definir bem o que é uma "palavra", conforme já discutido [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/450163/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348269/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401529/112052).

Se quer só considerar os casos simples (palavras estão sempre separadas por espaço, não há pontuação, etc) então a solução acima resolveria. Usar `find` pode acabar pegando trechos dentro de uma palavra (por exemplo, se a palavra proibida é "viado", usando `find` você bloquearia "enviado", o que não é o desejado).

> Na verdade filtros de palavras são um [problema antigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem) e até hoje [não está muito bem resolvido](https://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/). Mas enfim...

Nos links já citados acima ([esse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/450163/112052), [esse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348269/112052) e [esse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401529/112052)) você vai ver outras formas de quebrar uma frase em palavras, usando diferentes definições. Escolha a sua e troque o `split` do código acima pela opção de sua preferência.

---

Se quiser desconsiderar a diferença entre letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, você pode usar [`casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) para normalizar as palavras:

```
nomes_proibidos = list(map(str.casefold, ['Corona', 'Clorivaldo', 'Pfizernaldo', 'Hulk', 'Naruto', 'Goku', 'Cloroquina']))

def verificar_nome(frase):
    for palavra in frase.split():
        if palavra.casefold() in nomes_proibidos:
            return False
    return True
```

Claro que para casos mais simples, usar `lower` ou `upper` também funcionaria, mas a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) diz que `casefold` é mais "agressivo" e trata casos excepcionais como o caractere alemão `ß`, cuja versão maiúscula é "SS" (ou seja, para textos em português, `lower` ou `upper` seria o suficiente).

---

E por fim, em vez de uma lista de palavras, pode trocar para um `set`, já que operações de busca nesta estrutura [são mais rápidas do que em uma lista](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity):

```
# usar um set em vez de lista
nomes_proibidos = set(map(str.casefold, ['Corona', 'Clorivaldo', 'Pfizernaldo', 'Hulk', 'Naruto', 'Goku', 'Cloroquina']))
```

Claro que para poucos nomes, a diferença será imperceptível. Então teste para confirmar (mas a princípio, deve ser mais rápido que uma lista).

Fazendo um teste rápido com o [módulo `timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html):

```
from timeit import timeit

set_nomes_proibidos = set(map(str.casefold, ['Corona', 'Clorivaldo', 'Pfizernaldo', 'Hulk', 'Naruto', 'Goku', 'Cloroquina']))
list_nomes_proibidos = list(map(str.casefold, ['Corona', 'Clorivaldo', 'Pfizernaldo', 'Hulk', 'Naruto', 'Goku', 'Cloroquina']))

def verificar_nome_set(frase):
    for palavra in frase.split():
        if palavra.casefold() in set_nomes_proibidos:
            return False
    return True

def verificar_nome_list(frase):
    for palavra in frase.split():
        if palavra.casefold() in list_nomes_proibidos:
            return False
    return True

# frase com mil palavras, e com a palavra proibida no final
frase = ('abc ' * 1000) + 'Pedro Hulk da Silva'

# executa 10 mil vezes cada teste
params = { 'number' : 10000, 'globals': globals() }
# imprime os tempos em segundos
print(timeit('verificar_nome_set(frase)', **params))
print(timeit('verificar_nome_list(frase)', **params))
```

Na minha máquina, a solução com `set` foi ligeiramente mais rápida (cerca de 0,3 segundos em média), mas isso pode variar de acordo com o *hardware*, as frases e a lista de palavras proibidas, então cabe a você testar para os seus casos reais e ver se faz diferença.