# Regex capturando exatamente x digitos de uma string

Tags: regex

Estou tentando fazer uma expressão regular em que ela capture exatamente x dígitos(especificamente no meu caso x=6).

Exemplo:

"teste 1 n°123456 fim do teste"
"teste 2 n°7890123 fim do teste"

Quero que retorne na expressão regular apenas o "123456", ou seja, apenas números que contém exatamente 6 dígitos. Como poderia fazê-lo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pode utilizar a seguinte regex:

```
\b\d{6}\b
```

O `\d` é o meta caratere para digito, procurando um digito de 0 a 9.

O `{6}` indica que tem de encontrar 6 desses seguidos.

Os `\b` indicam que é inicio e fim de palavra, o que implica que tem de ser os 6 números seguidos, fazendo com que 7 ou mais números já não seja válido.

[Veja a funcionar no regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7bnJb7/1)

Funciona perfeitamente para o caso que mencionou. Se necessitar de algo mais amplo que funcione mesmo com os números seguidos ao texto, pode utilizar por exemplo esta regex, que já é um pouco mais complexa:

```
^|\D(\d{6})\D|$
```

Explicação:

```
^|\D    - Inicio de linha ou algo que não seja um digito
(\d{6}) - 6 dígitos seguidos e a serem capturados no grupo de captura 1
\D|$    - Seguido de algo que não seja um digito ou fim de linha
```

Aqui também usei o meta caratere `\D` que é o inverso do `\d`, e significa algo que não um digito.

Uma diferença subtil desta regex para a anterior é que nesta o digito encontra-se no grupo de captura 1, ao invés de na captura completa da regex. Por isso independentemente da forma como utilizar a regex em código, o obter do numero será sempre diferente.

[Veja no regex101](https://regex101.com/r/quQjNm/1)

Em território de regex é sempre assim. As mais simples regra geral são mais restritas e não controlam todos os casos, mas por vezes são exatamente o que precisa. Tem sempre de tentar encontrar um equilíbrio entre o que pretende validar e a complexidade/eficiência que está disposto a usar/abdicar.

Comment: Quanto mais estudo regex, mais percebo que o que vc disse no último parágrafo é verdade: achar o equilíbrio entre a exatidão e a complexidade é fundamental - e muitas vezes é difícil achar este ponto de equilíbrio. Se o sistema permitisse, eu daria mais um voto só por esse comentário :-) Aliás, outra alternativa é usar lookaheads e lookbehinds negativos: `(?<!\d)(\d{6})(?!\d)` - [veja](https://regex101.com/r/isuWza/2)

Comment: @hkotsubo É mesmo. Há muitos casos em que simplesmente não compensa a complexidade e perda de eficiência para controlar mais um ou outro caso que quase nunca acontecem, com regexs monstruosas com eu já vi algumas. Curiosamente eu comecei por fazer exatamente essa regex com lookahead negativo, mas acabei por trocar pela que tenho na resposta porque achei que ficava mais simples. Para alem disso alguns engines são mais restritivos em *lookbehind*

Answer (score 3):

Ótima resposta do @Isac que aplica o [meta-caractere `\b`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/110879/8063), porém, usando o `\b` só vai servir no seu caso específico. Eu gostaria de deixar aqui uma alternativa mais genérica.

O `\b` funciona no seu caso porque os 6 dígitos estão precedidos por um caractere especial `°` e sucedida por um espaço, ou seja, a string de captura entre dois `\b`'s só vai ser encontrada se ela estiver entre dois caracteres especias (exceto *underlined* `_`) ou espaço.

Por exemplo, se na primeira string citada na pergunta não tivesse o `°` antes do número (fosse assim: `n123456`), o número `123456` não seria encontrado com `\b`. Veja:

```js
var str = "teste 1 n123456 fim do teste";
console.log(/\b\d{6}\b/.test(str));
```

Isso porque o `\b`, como dito, exige que a string procurada esteja entre caracteres especiais.

Minha sugestão não é das mais elegantes, mas irá retornar o número (independente de onde esteja) que contenha 6 dígitos.

Veja:

```js
var string1 = "teste 1 n123456 fim do teste";
var string2 = "teste 2 n°7890123 fim do teste";

var teste1 = string1.match(/\d{6,}/);

if(teste1 && teste1[0].length == 6){
   console.log("'"+ teste1[0] +"' encontrado na string1");
}

var teste2 = string2.match(/\d{6,}/g);

if(teste2 && teste2[0].length == 6){
   console.log(teste2[0]);
}else{
   console.log("Nada encontrado na string2");
}
```

**O que o código faz?** Ele procura um número com **6 ou mais dígitos** e depois faz a comparação se esse número tem apenas 6 caracteres; se tiver, OK, caso contrário, não faz nada.