# Como pegar todas as tags, desde que não sejam descendentes de outra?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Atualmente tenho um texto, e quero obter algumas tags com as seguintes regras:

1. Obter a tag `p` e todo seu conteúdo.
2. Não selecionar tags `p` que tenha como parent uma tag `blockquote`.

Para pegar todos as tags `p` uso a regex `<p(.*?)<\/p>` e para pegar todas as tags `blockquote` uso `<blockquote(.*?)<\/blockquote>`.

Não estou conseguindo usar essas duas regex para atender o segunda regra.
Um texto exemplo, seria:

```html
<p>Nisi veniam dolore laborum consectetur consequat nostrud officia aliqua. Laborum excepteur occaecat voluptate est cupidatat nostrud deserunt sunt ex. Reprehenderit laboris fugiat voluptate est quis excepteur deserunt enim eiusmod.</p><p>Occaecat fugiat sint adipisicing nulla sint quis anim laborum in eiusmod id. Lorem sit velit deserunt irure adipisicing aliquip. Ad ipsum nulla adipisicing magna fugiat culpa duis consectetur et amet. Officia deserunt enim incididunt cupidatat aute sint laboris magna voluptate. Incididunt nostrud cillum ex ad Lorem ipsum eu irure sunt qui sint. Velit labore ipsum nisi exercitation.</p><blockquote><p>Occaecat officia aliquip aute labore enim nostrud anim laboris aliquip sunt irure enim. Culpa ea aliqua elit irure ut magna proident incididunt aliqua in et ex. Sit ex cillum dolore anim in pariatur duis cupidatat adipisicing non quis. Tempor aliquip aliquip cillum commodo dolore occaecat ad velit aliquip ipsum amet. Culpa Lorem consectetur voluptate cupidatat consequat. Quis ex irure amet eiusmod excepteur tempor magna excepteur proident.</p></blockquote><p>Consequat occaecat fugiat in velit nostrud ea anim adipisicing culpa esse. Ea irure fugiat occaecat duis enim adipisicing eiusmod eu eiusmod. Aliqua eiusmod voluptate officia duis reprehenderit velit irure ea consectetur ad nulla nulla ex.</p>
```

Uso o site https://regexr.com/ para fazer os testes.

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8686/137387

Comment: Realmente tinha ficado bem estranha a questão, como tinha inserido algumas tags HTML, elas foram interpretadas e acabaram não aparecendo, porém já corrigi.

Comment: Resumidamente, preciso pegar todas tags p, exceto as que estão dentro de um blockquote

Answer (score 1):

## Não use regex

Conforme já dito [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440262/112052) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) (e em muitos outros lugares, [basta procurar](https://www.google.com/search?q=why+is+it+bad+parse+html+with+regex)), regex não é a melhor ferramenta para manipular HTML (leia os links para entender os motivos).

Primeiro vou mostrar a solução mais simples, sem regex. E depois mostrar uma com regex pra você ver como não é o ideal (e ainda mostrar como ela falha em vários casos).

No seu caso, para pegar os `p` que não estão dentro de um `blockquote`, basta usar [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) e no seletor usar a [pseudo-classe `:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not):

```js
// pega todos os "p" que não são descendentes de blockquote
for (const p of document.querySelectorAll('p:not(blockquote *)')) {
    console.log(p.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<p>parágrafo 1</p>
<p>parágrafo 2</p>
<blockquote><p>dentro de blockquote</p></blockquote>
<div>
  <p><span>Um <a href="">parágrafo</a> dentro <i>de uma div</i> e</span> com <b>outras</b> tags dentro</p>
</div>
<blockquote>
  <div>
    <p>dentro de uma div, dentro de um blockquote</p>
  </div>
</blockquote>
<!-- <p>comentado</p> -->
```

Primeiro, `blockquote *` pega todos os elementos que sejam descendentes de um `blockquote`. Depois `p:not` pega todos os `p` que não se encaixam nesse critério. Ou seja, no final tenho todos os `p` que não são descendentes de um `blockquote`.

**Repare que ele também não pega o parágrafo "*dentro de uma div, dentro de um blockquote*", pois o seletor `blockquote *` pega todos os descendentes, sejam "filhos" diretos, "netos", "bisnetos", etc. Mas se a ideia é excluir apenas os `p` que são filhos diretos de um `blockquote` (mas tem que incluir os "netos", "bisnetos", etc), basta mudar para `p:not(blockquote > *)`.**

No caso, o código acima pega somente três parágrafos: os dois primeiros e o quarto (o que tem várias tags dentro dele). Os demais estão dentro de um `blockquote` e são ignorados. Repare também que o parágrafo comentado é corretamente ignorado.

Pronto, é só isso. E uma vez tendo os elementos, você faz o que quiser com eles. No caso, eu peguei o `innerHTML`, que pega todo o conteúdo da tag. Mas se você também quer incluir as próprias tags `p`, basta trocar para `outerHTML`.

---

Como você disse que "tem um texto", isso pode dar a entender que na verdade tem uma string contendo o HTML. Neste caso, basta transformar a string em um `HTMLDocument` e depois usar `querySelectorAll`:

```js
// string contendo o HTML
const texto = `<p>parágrafo 1</p>
<p>parágrafo 2</p>
<blockquote><p>dentro de blockquote</p></blockquote>
<div>
  <p><span>Um <a href="">parágrafo</a> dentro <i>de uma div</i> e</span> com <b>outras</b> tags dentro</p>
</div>
<blockquote>
  <div>
    <p>dentro de uma div, dentro de um blockquote</p>
  </div>
</blockquote>
<!-- <p>comentado</p> -->`;
    
// converte a string para um HTMLDocument
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(texto, 'text/html');
// faz a busca (igual ao código anterior)
for (const p of doc.querySelectorAll('p:not(blockquote *)')) {
    console.log(p.innerHTML);
}
```

---

## Quer mesmo usar regex?

Bom, pra começar, a regex `<p(.*?)<\/p>` falha se o HTML for assim:

```html
<pre>bla</pre><p>abc</p>
```

Pois `<p(.*?)` basicamente significa "`<p` seguido de zero ou mais caracteres, seguido de `</p>`". E como `<pre>` começa com `<p` e está seguido de vários caracteres, e termina com `</p>`, então a regex pega tudo desde o `<pre>` até o `</p>`, veja: https://regex101.com/r/yh9Y9z/1

Até daria para resolver com algo como `<p\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/p>`: o `\b` garante que depois do `<p` não vai ter outro caractere alfanumérico, o que evita o problema acima com a tag `pre` (veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110874/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/420487/112052) para mais detalhes sobre o `\b`), e `[^>]*` verifica por zero ou mais caracteres que não sejam `>`, assim o `p` pode ter vários atributos (ou nenhum) antes do `>`.

Mas na minha opinião já está começando a complicar além do necessário. Sem contar que ainda precisamos ver se o `p` não está dentro de um `blockquote`, que seria mais ou menos assim (**atenção, ainda não funciona para todos os casos**):

```js
// não funciona 100%, pois pega o "p" que está comentado
const regex = /<blockquote.*?<\/blockquote>|(<p\b[^>]*>.*?<\/p>)/gs;
for (const match of document.body.innerHTML.matchAll(regex)) {
    if (match[1]) {
        console.log(match[1]);
    }
}
```

```html
<p>parágrafo 1</p>
<p>parágrafo 2</p>
<blockquote><p>dentro de blockquote</p></blockquote>
<div>
  <p><span>Um <a href="">parágrafo</a> dentro <i>de uma div</i> e</span> com <b>outras</b> tags dentro</p>
</div>
<blockquote>
  <div>
    <p>dentro de uma div, dentro de um blockquote</p>
  </div>
</blockquote>
<!-- <p>comentado</p> -->
```

A regex usa [um pequeno "truque"](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick): ela primeiro tenta pegar um `blockquote`, e se não encontrar, tenta pegar um `p`. Mas o `p` está entre parênteses, [o que forma um grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Então basta eu testar se o grupo está presente no *match*: se não estiver, é porque pegou um `blockquote` (e aí eu posso ignorar completamente, nem preciso ver se tem um `p` dentro). Se tiver o grupo, eu sei que caiu no segundo caso e o `p` não está dentro de um `blockquote`.

Ela usa a *flag* `s` para que o ponto também pegue as quebras de linha, assim as tags podem estar em linhas diferentes.

Mas repare que a regex também pega o parágrafo que está comentado (e que entendo que não deveria). Embora seja possível fazer uma regex que detecta comentários, [ela é tão complicada](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42097865) que não vale a pena (ainda mais em uma regex que na minha opinião já não está lá muito legível e fácil de entender e manter - sem contar que não fiz testes extensivos, pois o HTML pode ficar tão complexo que sempre pode ter um caso que a regex não detecta, e aí para arrumar ela acaba ficando ainda mais complexa).

Enfim, se tivesse que escolher, eu não usaria regex. Nos comentários você disse que "precisa ser usando regex", mas repense se realmente "precisa", já que a primeira solução acima é muito mais simples e correta.

Answer (score -3):

```
(?<=(<blockquote><p>))(\w|\d|\n|[().,\-:;@#$%^&*\[\]"'+–/\/®°⁰!?{}|`~]| )+?(?=(</p></blockquote>))
```

Tem outra forma também:

```js
function get_string(string, start, end) {
    str =  string.split(start);
    str = str[1].split(end);

    return str[0];
}

let texto = '<blockquote><p>Hello</p></blockquote>';
console.log(get_string(texto, '<blockquote><p>', '</p></blockquote>'));
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: **Não use regex para manipular HTML/XML**, como já bem explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129557/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/440262/112052), e por último mas não menos importante, [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454). Prefira usar alguma biblioteca específica (toda linguagem possui).

Comment: `\w|\d` é redundante, porque o `\w` já engloba todos os caracteres que `\d` representa. De qualquer forma, usar regex para manipular HTML tem uma série de problemas, todos muito bem explicados nos links do comentário acima...

Comment: Aliás, podia juntar tudo na mesma classe de caracteres: `[\w\s().,etc...]` - lembrando que [o `\s` já pega os espaços e quebras de linha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052). De qualquer forma, essa regex é bem limitada, basta que tenha uma única tag dentro do `p` que já não funciona mais: https://regex101.com/r/78Szcl/1 - sem contar que não contempla os casos em que cada tag está em uma linha, por exemplo (o que é perfeitamente válido em HTML), ou que tenha comentários entre uma e outra, ou simplesmente um espaço entre elas (e que a solução com `split` também não resolve...)

Comment: A questão estava bem estranha, como tinha inserido algumas tags HTML, elas foram interpretadas e acabaram não aparecendo, porém já corrigi.

No escopo do problema que estou resolvendo, precisa ser usando REGEX, resumidamente, preciso pegar todas tags p, exceto as que estão dentro de um blockquote.