# Regex R singular e plural

Tags: r, regex

Estou escrevendo um loop que eu preciso extrair a palavra "conselho" ou "conselhos" e as três palavras seguintes (se existirem) de um conjunto de textos. No entanto, as diferentes soluções que eu escrevo não estão funcionando.

Fato: a regex `conselho(?:\\s+\\w+){1,3}` funciona se eu quero "conselho de estado" , mas não para "conselhos de estado", e eu queria pegar as duas expressões.

**Primeira tentativa:** |

A regex `conselho(?:\\s+\\w+){1,3}|conselhos(?:\\s+\\w+){1,3}` em tese funciona, mas no meu loop ela acaba retornando as ocorrências duplicadas. Não entendi exatamente o porquê.

Aqui está um exemplo do que ele encontra:

```
                              termo
1 conselhos tanto representantes de
2 conselhos tanto representantes de
3 conselhos tanto representantes de
4     conselhos deveriam ser vistos
5     conselhos deveriam ser vistos
6     conselhos deveriam ser vistos
7     conselho nacional de política
8     conselho nacional de política
```

Segunda tentativa: +(s)

Na segunda vez eu tentei extrair com a seguinte regex `conselho+(s)(?:\\s+\\w+){1,3}`, o resultado foi que ele só encontra os termos "conselhos" e ignora o "conselho"

```
termo
1 conselhos tanto representantes de
2 conselhos tanto representantes de
3 conselhos tanto representantes de
4     conselhos deveriam ser vistos
5     conselhos deveriam ser vistos
6     conselhos deveriam ser vistos
```

Qual é a regex correta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A sua primeira tentativa não deveria duplicar, afinal a regex busca por um ou outro, e se encontrar um deles, não deveria buscar pelo outro. Mas enfim, dá para fazer de forma mais simples, como já veremos abaixo.

A sua segunda tentativa não funciona porque `conselho+(s)` significa:

- a palavra "conselh"
- `o+` - a letra `o` [repetida](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) uma ou mais vezes
- `(s)` - a letra `s`

Portanto, este trecho vai pegar palavras como "conselhos", "conselhoooos", "conselhooooooooooooos", mas não "conselho".

Se quer que o `s` seja opcional, [basta colocar `?` depois dele](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html), assim:

```
conselhos?(?:\\s+\\w+){1,3}
```

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/551530/112052) usa `s*`, que também funciona, mas o problema é que o `*` significa "zero ou mais ocorrências", ou seja, se tiver algo como "conselhoss", também vai pegar. Já usando `s?`, eu garanto que só pode ter zero ou uma ocorrência do `s` (claro que se seu texto não tem esses casos errados, não terá problemas).

Quanto a "*três palavras seguintes (se existirem)*", quer dizer que se não tiver nenhuma palavra depois de "conselho"/"conselhos", também serve? Se for este o caso, bastaria trocar `{1,3}` por `{0,3}`.

---

Vale lembrar ainda que o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w` também inclui dígitos e o caractere `_`. Ou seja, coisas como `abc_123` ou `1_000` serão consideradas "palavras". Se quer restringir para apenas letras, basta trocar para:

```
conselhos?(?:\\s+\\b[[:alpha:]]+\\b){1,3}
```

No caso, acrescentei o atalho `\b` ([*word boundary*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), explicado em mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/420487/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/528763/112052)), para que ele desconsidere casos como `abc_123` (sem o `\b`, ele considera que o trecho `abc` é a palavra, com o `\b`, ele desconsidera completamente o `abc_123` e não inclui nos resultados).

Comment: Obrigado por reparar que se `s*` repete o `s` zero ou *mais* vezes também pega *vários* esses.

Answer (score 5):

A regex está lá quase, basta acrescentar `[s]*` (opcional `s` zero ou mais vezes) logo a seguir a `"conselho"` e mudar o máximo de repetições da expressão que se segue para 2.

```r
x <- c(
  "conselho de estado",
  "conselhos de estado",
  "outro sem conslh",
  "conselhos tanto representantes de",
  "conselhos deveriam ser vistos",
  "conselho nacional de política"
)

m <- regexpr("conselho[s]*(?:\\s+\\w+\\>){1,2}", x)
regmatches(x, m)
#> [1] "conselho de estado"             "conselhos de estado"           
#> [3] "conselhos tanto representantes" "conselhos deveriam ser"        
#> [5] "conselho nacional de"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

Depois de ler a excelente resposta do [hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/551534/82237), eis duas regex corrigidas. A primeira só com o `"s*"` mudado e a segunda também com `"[[:alpha:]]"` em vez de `"\\w"`.

**1.**

```
m <- regexpr("conselhos?(?:\\s+\\w+\\>){1,2}", x)
```

**2.**

```
m <- regexpr("conselhos?(?:\\s+\\[[:alpha:]]+\\>){1,2}", x)
```